# Modify all elements from a List<T> starting at an index

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a `List<MemberData>` `storeCustomers` with the following type in C#,

```
public class MemberData
{
   public string clientId;
   public string displayName;
   public bool isBlocked;
}
```

Let's say my list has 100 members with different `clientId` and `displayName`, but all have the same `isBlocked = true`. If I want to change the same field starting at the index 35 until the end, for `isBlocked = false`, how do I do it? I want to keep the same List and avoid truncating.

Comment: `foreach(var item in list.Skip(35))` ?

Comment: `foreach` or a `for` loop with the correct starting index?

Comment: did you try `list.Skip(35).ToList()` ? This would create a new list where you can change property of all elements.

Comment: No actual piece of code used in production would (or rather should) have "index 35" hardcoded. Hopefully you have some other condition to select the elements to modify.

Comment: Sure, but that's out of scope of his question, so I understant giving a fixed value as an example.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's true, my list should take at a given moment, the top down 50% of those customers and mark them as unblocked or `isBlocked = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `for` or `foreach` loop, because you need to cause side effects to your list.

You can use the `Skip` Linq method to ignore all entries before the given index. Then process the entries as normal.

```
foreach (var entry in yourList.Skip(35))
{
    entry.isBlocked = false;
}
```

Comment: It should be `Skip(35)` to start at index 35.

Comment: I think I have the exact same solution written down, but I would prefer not to use a for each loop, as my list can grow up to 10k.

Comment: Um, what is the difference between `foreach` and `.ForEach()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way, but it appears not to be optimized as it uses a `ForEach`.

So using `System.Linq`,

```
int skipIndex = 35;
storeCustomers.Skip(skipIndex).ToList().ForEach(x => x.isBlocked = true);
```

Is there's a faster and more performant way to do this task? (probably no using Threading of course).

Comment: of course it uses a foreach loop, how else would you enumerate the collection?

Comment: @gunr2171 ah, I was thinking about a `ForEach` for `IEnumerable`, since creating a new list is rather unnecessary. And *that* is not packaged with LINQ, even if it is [common to add it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a "for" loop

```
for(var i = 35; i < storeCustomers.Count() - 35; i++)
{
    storeCustomers[i] = false;
}
```