# Lambda Expression using Foreach Clause

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

**EDIT**

For reference, here's the blog post which eric referred to in the comments

https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

**ORIG**

More of a curiosity I suppose but one for the C# Specification Savants...

Why is it that the ForEach() clause doesn't work (or isn't available) for use on IQueryable/IEnumerable result sets...

You have to first convert your results ToList() or ToArray()
Presumably theres a technical limitation to the way C# iterates IEnumerables Vs. Lists...
Is it something to do with the Deferred Execution's of IEnumerables/IQuerable Collections.
e.g.

```
var userAgentStrings = uasdc.UserAgentStrings
    .Where<UserAgentString>(p => p.DeviceID == 0 && 
                            !p.UserAgentString1.Contains("msie"));
//WORKS            
userAgentStrings.ToList().ForEach(uas => ProcessUserAgentString(uas));         

//WORKS
Array.ForEach(userAgentStrings.ToArray(), uas => ProcessUserAgentString(uas));

//Doesn't WORK
userAgentStrings.ForEach(uas => ProcessUserAgentString(uas));
```

Comment: I'd write `ForEach(uac => ProcessUserAgentString(uas))` as `ForEach(ProcessUserAgentString)`.

Comment: What's the problem with a conventional for-each loop?

    foreach (var uas in UserAgentStrings) ProcessUserAgentString(uas);

Comment: Theres no problem... Like I said, it was more of a curiousity why the convention was available to use on Arrays/Lists but not on IQueryables/IEnumerables and as Eric Lippert pointed out below, it's a completely philosophical choice by the dev team and not for any technical reasons

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet

Comment: Here's an alternative idea of how this *could* be possible: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16501309-shorthand-to-execute-method-in-foreach-loop

Comment: Here is the updated link as the blogs.msdn link is dead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach

Answer (score 15):

It's perfectly possible to write a `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`.

I'm not really sure why it isn't included as a built-in extension method:

- Maybe because `ForEach` already existed on `List<T>` and `Array` prior to LINQ.
- Maybe because it's easy enough to use a `foreach` loop to iterate the sequence.
- Maybe because it wasn't felt to be functional/LINQy enough.
- Maybe because it isn't chainable. (It's easy enough to make a chainable version that `yield`s each item after performing an action, but that behaviour isn't particularly intuitive.)

---

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: point taken, but the question was more in reference to why it's not available out of the box... i.e. Array has a static `ForEach()` method. List has one... Why don't IEnumerable/IQueryable

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for Eric's blog post to find out the real answer ;)

Comment: Your guesses are remarkably similar to my posting.