# why .net c# lack of "EACH"

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a .Each() (or .ForEach() ) iterator in the .Net standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294733/is-there-a-each-or-foreach-iterator-in-the-net-standard-library)

Maybe I am wrong, but I don't see the "EACH" function in .net (3.0)?

We can

```
IEnumerable<T>.Select().Where().First().Any()
```

Why don't we have

`IEnumberable<T>.Each(Action<T> action)`?

So instead of 2 lines:
`Foreach(T t in list)
  action(t)`;

we can just call
`list.Each((t)=>{blah;blah;})`?

Is there a concern for performance?

Comment: the answers on the linked dup cover this

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230538/foreach-in-or-foreach-that-is-the-question) and it's answers.

Comment: This one has an answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause/859068#859068

Answer (score 2):

Frequently asked, definitively answered:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: +1 I always wondered about that myself... thanks for the interesting link!

Answer (score 1):

[List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It was made this way, since none of the extention methods on `IEnumerable` was supposed to have any side effects, and a `ForEach` would have side effects as it's primary objective.

It was deemed that a `foreach` loop is not much more verbose to write out.