# Linq - Is there a IEnumerable.ForEach<T> extension method that I'm missing?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Lambda Expression using Foreach Clause…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause)
>   [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

This seems pretty basic. I'm trying to iterate over each object of an IEnumerable. It appears that I would have to cast it to a list first. Is that right? It seems to me there should be an extension method on IEnumerable that does this. I keep having to right my own and I'm getting tired of it. Am I missing it somewhere?

```
myEnumerable.ToList().ForEach(...)
```

I want to do this:

```
myEnumerable.ForEach(...)
```

Comment: Highly recommend MoreLinq: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/, by Jon Skeet and team.  Includes this operator and many more.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface

Answer (score 4):

Nope, there isn't a built-in `ForEach` extension method. It's easy enough to roll your own though:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But why bother? As [Eric Lippert explains in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), the standard `foreach` statement is more readable -- and philosophically more appropriate -- than a side-effecting `ForEach` method:

```
myEnumerable.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
// vs
foreach (var x in myEnumerable) Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: But it's really stupid if I want to do this: 

var results = myenumerable.Where(...).Select(...)
foreach(var result in results){ .... }

I would rather do somethign like this instead: myenumerable.Where(...).Select(...).ForEach(...)

Comment: @Micah: Well, if you want to do that then just go ahead and use the extension method in my answer.

Comment: @Micah: If you would rather do that, then do that. It's a *single line of code in an extension method*. What's stopping you?

Comment: @Eric: I've already done it, I just still don't get the rationale behind why not to include it as part of the framework. Especially considering the guys who wrote List<T> and .AsParallel() thought it was worth including.

Comment: @Micah: List<T>.ForEach adds value; because it can use internal implementation details of List<T> it can optimize its implementation. (Whether it actually does so or not I do not know.)  The parallel ForEach adds value; it can execute a sequence of actions in parallel. Neither of these value-adds are available for an extension method on IEnumerable<T>, which cannot see internal implementation details and does not execute in parallel. It adds neither value nor representational power; it's just a confusing and possibly slower way to rewrite perfectly sensible looping code.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't. Eric Lippert talks about why this feature was omitted in his [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx):

> A number of people have asked me why there is no Microsoft-provided “ForEach” sequence operator extension method.

As a summary the two main reasons are:

- Using `ForEach` violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon - no side-effects.
- A `ForEach` method would add no new representational power to the language. You can easily achieve the same effect more clearly using a foreach statement.

Comment: That's a stupid reason. You can achieve all the functionality of the linq extensions using a for each loop.

Comment: @Micah: Sure and you can also achieve the same effect as any LINQ extension method by writing it directly in CIL, but I don't think it's **more clear**.

Comment: What's so unclear about myEnumerable.ForEach(...)?

Comment: It seems stupid when you chain a bunch of calls together like myEnumerable.Where(...).Select(...) to not just add a .ForEach(...) to the very end of it instead of having to write a seperate "foreach" code block.

Comment: Also, if it's so bad to do it, why did the PLinq team implement it? .AsParallel().ForAll(...)

Comment: @Micah: That article actually mentions that they have a ForEach too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx

Comment: I wish foreach of you to take it easy and forall of you to stop flagging each other's comments.

Comment: In the end, we are going for the side effects. When so many asks for it, why not implement it? The functional purist can decide not to use it, it's a free world.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such extension method.  `List<T>` exposes a real method called [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) (which has been there since .NET 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

There's some talk about it [here](http://www.davesquared.net/2008/03/ienumerable-and-foreach.html).  It's not build in to the frame work, but you can roll your own extension method and use it that way.  This is probably your best bet from what I can tell.

I've been in the same situation.

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
    foreach (var item in source) {
      action(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable do not have this extension method.

Read Eric Lippert's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for the reasoning behind it.

So if you need it, you will hav eto write it yourself :)