# ForEach -- where are you?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

I love the .ForEach method on List<T> in C#.  How is this not one of the suite of Extension Methods on IEnumerable<T>?

Why do I have to call .ToList() my collection in order to call an action on each element?  Please tell me why?  Thank you.

```
List<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action);
```

Comment: See this link for a pretty definitive explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: There are no elements available to loop over with foreach until you actually execute the query by using ToList()

Comment: @JK - If I can 'Count()' and get 'First()' why cant I act on each element?

Comment: @dlex -- i will review, why is that not a subitted answer?

Comment: @Glenn It's not my answer, it's someone else's. I try to just post links as comments unless they're directly to documentation.

Comment: Because Count and First are for querying, whereas ForEach is for acting. Eric Lippert has the exact reasoning here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been much discussion over this topic:

See:

- [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)
- [Lambda Expression using Foreach Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause)

Answer (score 3):

Language INtegrated *Query* (LINQ).  Not Language Integrated Extensions (LIEs).

You are particularly speaking of LINQ-to-objects.  The other LINQs (to-SQL, to-XML), etc. would have more trouble implementing arbitrary logic.

Nothing stops you from implementing it yourself, though.

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void ForEach<T> (this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
   {
      foreach (T item in items)
      {
         action (item);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, so why not an extension method with all of the others on IEnumerable-T??