# Is there a way to set values in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better way to do these assignments with LINQ?

```
IEnumerable<SideBarUnit> sulist1 = newlist.Where(c => c.StatusID == EmergencyCV.ID);
foreach (SideBarUnit su in sulist1) su.color = "Red";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No.

You can do such a thing, as the other answers here point out, but then **you are no longer using LINQ**.

Eric Lippert wrote [an excellent blog post about this very subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), which I highly recommend you read.  Here is an excerpt:

> I am *philosophically* opposed to providing such a method, for two reasons.
>
> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly **the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects.**
>
> The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect.
>
> ...
>
> The second reason is that doing so adds zero new representational power to the language. Doing this lets you rewrite this perfectly clear code:
>
> ```
> foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
> ```
>
> into this code:
>
> ```
> foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });
> ```
>
> which uses almost exactly the same characters in slightly different order. And yet the second version is harder to understand, harder to debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing object lifetimes in subtle ways.

Comment: +1 Others have mentioned it, and others have gone ahead and showed examples of ForEach(). I couldn't agree more with Eric Lippert here. Perhaps explicitly posting this excerpt will convince the OP, or maybe not. Still, the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to define a `foreach` extension method which allows you to add it onto the end of a query of this sort.  For example

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action) {
  foreach (var cur in enumerable) {
    action(cur);
  }
}

...
```

usage:

```
newlist
  .Where(c => c.StatusID == EmergencyCV.ID)
  .ForEach(cur => cur.color = "Red");
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [List.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<SideBarUnit> sulist1 = 
   newlist.Where(c => c.StatusID == EmergencyCV.ID)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(item => item.color = "Red");
```

PS: I know about Eric Lippert's [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) aboout `ForEach() vs foreach`, but anyway it is useful and I preffer it rather than `for/foreach` loops

**EDIT:** regarding question in comment about performance hits

`Enumerable.ToList()` implemented as

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

so performance hit is a time to create a new `List<>()` instance.

MSDN says next for [List<>(IEnumerable<>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) ctor:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that contains elements
>   **copied** from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.

So there is would be a copy operation of all list

Comment: In other words, the collection is looped twice

Comment: `ForEach` isn't a Linq-exclusive "feature", though. In fact, it is entirely unrelated to Linq. So, I assume your answer, really, is "no, but here's an alternative." Advice as to _[why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838458/is-there-a-way-to-set-values-in-linq/7838525#7838525)_ would be a great piece of input to this answer - rather than the OP coming away with a false impression that this is Linq.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment : absolutely, LINQ end up after the `ToLisT()` call

Answer (score 4):

Linq is all about selecting, not updating.
But you could use ToList and List's ForEach to update the elements:

```
newlist.Where(c => c.StatusID == EmergencyCV.ID).
  ToList().
  ForEach(su => su.color = "Red");
```

I'm not sure the readability is better though...

Comment: @vs 74 Is there a performance hit when converting from IEnum<> to a List<>?

Comment: @iterationx, well a new list is going to be created so it's not as efficient as iterating + I think it's less readable so I'm not sure it's worth using this technique...

Answer (score 2):

LINQs purpose is mainly to query/project/transform data.

You might want to use the ForEach extension method. But see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858978/25727) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous method in a Select statement:

```
var sulist1 = newlist.Where(c => c.StatusID == EmergencyCV.ID)
                     .Select(c => {
                                     c.color = "Red";
                                     return c;
                                  });
```

Comment: Actually I don't believe this will work unless the new list is iterated