# Replacing a foreach with a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert this code to linq:

```
foreach (var printer in printers)
{
    if (printer.Installed)
        installedPrinters.Add(printer);
}
```

I am new to Linq and would appreciate pointers on how it works when iterating through a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printers.Where(printer => printer.Installed)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(printer => installedPrinters.Add(printer));
```

Note the need to call ToList() before ForEach (see [Lambda Expression using Foreach Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause)).

Also note that while this works, your original code is probably easier to read... LINQ is cool but don't feel obligated to use it for everything :)

Comment: I'd also mention that one of the principal developers of c# compiler team (Eric Lippert) [doesn't particularly like the LINQ `.ForEach()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) (nor do I).  The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect.

Comment: More simply, `printer => installedPrinters.Add(printer)` could be `installedPrinters.Add`.

Comment: @Ripple and how do you suppose your alternative would know which printer in the foreach to install?

Comment: @ErikPhilips `ForEach` has a signiature of `Action<Printer>` which `void Add(Printer printer)` fulfills. It just passes the argument in the same way the lambada does. (I agree with your fist comment too btw, he should not be using `ForEach`)

Comment: @ErikPhilips Each printer will be passed by `ForEach` as @Scott commented. In addition, I assume `installedPrinters.Add` returns `void`. Sorry for my insufficient words.

Comment: @Ripple no problem.  It was my attempt at adding some extra metadata to the answer so other readers would understand.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to create a new list, you could always just do:

```
var installedPrinters = printers.Where(p => p.Installed).ToList();
```

If you are adding to a list that may already have items in it, then you could try:

```
installedPrinters.AddRange(printers.Where(p => p.Installed));
```

Assuming your installedPrinters is actually a collection that supports AddRange such as List.

Answer (score 1):

So first use a `Where` to filter the Installed==true, then run over them with `ForEach`:

```
printers.Where(p => p.Installed).ForEach(p => installedPrinters.Add(p));
```

Comment: Note that Robert's answer is more accurate as it includes the ToList

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var printer in printers.Where (p => p.Installed) { installedPrinters.Add(printer); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
printer.Where(x => x.Installed).ToList()
      .ForEach(
          p=>
            {
              installedPrinters.Add(p)
            }
);
```