# How can I write foreach loop to sum elements in lamba expression?

Tags: c#, foreach, lambda, linq-expressions

How can I write foreach loop shown below as a labmda expression?

```
var sum = 0;
foreach (SomeClass obj in SomeListOfClass)
{
   sum += obj.SomeValue;
}
```

I am expecting a lambda expression that look like this

```
var sum = SomeListOfClass.ForEachMethod( x => sum += x.SomeValue)
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could just use Linq's `Sum` extension method `var sum = SomeListOfClass.Sum(x => x.SomeValue);`

Comment: This may help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858978/lambda-expression-using-foreach-clause)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? What's exactly wrong with the question. Didn't understand?

Comment: @talaa123 Well, your code doesn't make much sense (why are you adding to `sum` in the lambda and also setting it to the return value?) and you apparently didn't look at the documentation, where you would find `Sum()` and `ForEach()`. You also didn't explain why do you want to use a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Use Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

var sum = list.Sum(x => x.SomeValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the special case at hand (sum), you can use Linq's `Sum` method.

```
SomeListOfClass.Sum(c => c.Property);
```

This however, is just a special case of `Aggregate`. If you need more complicate aggregation of your list, you'd use that.
Here is an example that sums up the values of integers:

```
var ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var x = ints.Aggregate((start, current) => start + current);
```