# c# DataGridView getting contents from a Row/Column

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns.

When a user double clicks the row, I want to revtrieve data from the 1st column of the clicked row.

```
    private void ticketsDataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Row " + e.RowIndex); // gets me the row selected

    }
```

How can I get the column for the selected row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [DataGridView.Rows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx)

try this on doublic click event.

```
DataGridViewRow row =dataGridView.Rows[0];

string someStringColumnValue = (string)row.Cells[0].Value;
```

Ref: [C# - Lambda syntax for looping over DataGridView.Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451693/c-sharp-lambda-syntax-for-looping-over-datagridview-rows)