# Simple way to update IEnumerable objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Assume I have a business object like this,

```
class Employee
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
        public string desgination;
        public int grade;
    }

    List<Employee> lstEmp = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { name="A",desgination="SE",id=1},
            new Employee() { name="b",desgination="TL",id=2},
            new Employee() { name="c",desgination="PL",id=3},
            new Employee() { name="d",desgination="SE",id=4},
            new Employee() { name="e",desgination="SSE",id=5},
        };
```

And if I want to update the employee grade to 3 whose designation is "SE", then I have to write something like this

```
lstEmp=lstEmp.Select(x =>
            {
                x.grade = (x.desgination == "SE") ? 3 : x.grade;
                    return x;
            }).ToList();
```

But here when using select it will generate new employee object everytime, not updating the existing lstEmp, so I have to reassgin the updated list to lstEmp.

It seems to me it affects the performance when updating large updates frequently. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This question has some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe default LINQ methods doenst support inline updates. but you can create your own extension methods to achive this

```
  public static void Update<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> outer, Action<TSource> updator)
        {
            foreach (var item in outer)
            {
                updator(item);
            }


        }
```

and use it like this

```
 lstEmp.Update(x => x.grade = (x.desgination == "SE") ? 3 : x.grade);
```

Comment: It's NOT possible with ForEach() because it's Read Only statut inside foreach.

Answer (score 19):

Actually, your existing `Select` call *is* modifying the original objects themselves - it's not creating new employee objects. What makes you think it *is* creating new `Employee` instances? After all, you haven't got `new Employee` anywhere within the lambda expression.

You could iterate through the results of calling `Select` without ever calling `ToList`, and you'd still see changes afterwards. This means your projection has *side-effects* - that's generally a bad idea. You do have to make *something* iterate over the results of the projection though. Just calling `Count()` would do it, for example. LINQ queries use deferred execution in many cases: they don't apply the projection/predicate/etc until the result is needed.

LINQ is designed to work in a functional way: side-effects are discouraged, just as you wouldn't expect a normal SELECT query on a database to change the contents of the table it's querying. Side-effect-free code is great in terms of readability and the ability to reason about code.

If you want to change values rather than create new ones, I would suggest a simple `foreach` loop instead. It's not what LINQ is designed for. However, I would personally try to stick to immutable types, use LINQ, and measure the performance as you go - I suspect you'll find that in many cases it's not as bad as you think.

Answer (score 1):

I would Say LINQ is mainaly used for Selection of data  once you get the data , you can use ForEach construct to update the data

Answer (score -2):

```
lstEmp = lstEmp.Select(X => new Employee
        {
            desgination =X.desgination ,
            grade =X.desgination=="SE"?3:X.grade ,
            id=X.id ,
            name =X.name 
        }).ToList();
```