# Why does IEnumerable<T> only have the "out" covariant flag and not "in" c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ienumerable, covariance

I was wondering , why does `IEnumerable<T>` has ONLY the `out` and not the  `in` contravariant flag ?

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

I can understand the `out` by this example :

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

`object` is bigger than `string` , so the compiler afraid that well do something like:

```
 objects = objects.First().Select(x=>5);// ( we cant insert int to string...)
```

fine and understood.

but what about if i want to use the IEnumerable as **insertion**?

something like :

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = ...;
IEnumerable<string> strings = objects
```

so i can also INSERT into objects  ...

but the problem is that there is no `IEnumerable<in T>` ...

am I missing something here?

Comment: @downvoter , care to explain please ?

Comment: what do you mean with "INSERT into objects", you can't insert into `IEnumerable` and I can't see an insertion anywhere in your question? What is your real problem?

Comment: @TomasJansson  I want to be able to insert strings values into objects. but Ienumerable doesnt has `In ` it is only out

Comment: Almost like [why-was-ienumerablet-made-covariant-in-c-sharp-4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732299/why-was-ienumerablet-made-covariant-in-c-sharp-4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert into `IEnumerable`. There is, unfortunately, no "IInsertable".

There is no interface to tell that you can only add items to a collection. This would be an `in` generic type. Because you can get the items on every collection interface, it is not possible to have `in` generic arguments.

**Edit**

The interface `IEnumerable<T>` has only getters, so you can't insert any elements to the collection using that interface. Because of that, `out` is allowed in the declaration of `IEnumerable<out T>`. It tells the compiler, that values of type `T` are only going in one direction, the are "coming out". This makes it compatible in one direction. You can use `IEnumerable<string>`as an `IEnumerable<object>`, because you are only reading from it. You can read a string as an object. But you couldn't write to it, you couldn't pass an object as a string. It might be an integer or any other type.

Comment: i didnt tent to insert into Ienumerable but VIA Iernumerable

Comment: @Royi: My question is: *how* would you insert *via* IEnumerable?

Comment: so what you telling me is that i cant udpate Ienumerable types ? what about `strings =strings .Select(x=>"myInsertedString")` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir that is not inserting, that is replacing the whole list.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans this is changing the current list ... i didnt make any *new obj* here...

Comment: @Royi: To be very precise: You can't update a type using `IEnumerable<T>`. Of course you can update for instance a `List<T>`, but not using the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you don't have to use `new obj` for it to be a new object. What you are doing in you example is not changing the list, you are just applying a "filter" to your current list and then assigning the result to your existing variable. The result from your filtering is new, the variable is just a pointer to any object of that type.

Comment: @TomasJansson read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930510/simple-way-to-update-ienumerable-objects-using-linq with jon skeet answer.... he is actualy says that you ARE CHANGING the values and not creating new ones !

Comment: @Royi: No, in that case, it is changing the elements in the collection, not the collection itself. The collection implements IEnumerable, and it does not change.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger so the out in `IEnumerable<out T>` tells me that i cant insert via it  ???? or as a general rule - the Ienumerable can be used to insert...? or is it just because `public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    // Properties
    T Current { get; }
}
` has only get accessor....?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think the word you are looking for is "assign" (not "insert"). In your example: `IEnumerable<string> strings = objects` is assignment not insertion (neither collection nor its elements are changed in any way - you just treat it slightly differently from the perspective of the type system).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, you are changing the values but not the collection itself. I've extended my answer to include a little information about covariance and contravariance.

Comment: It's too much for a comment, so I add a section to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert has a [series of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) on this prior to introducing co/contravariance in C# which is worth a read.

a simple example would be

```
public class Animal(){
...
}

public class Giraf(){
   public void LookAboveTheClouds(){}
}

IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new list<Animal>{
                                    new Elephant(),
                                    new Tiger(), 
                                    new TinyMouse()};
IEnumerable<Giraf> girafs = animals;

foreach(var giraf in girafs){
   //elephants,tigers and tiny mice does not suuport this
   giraf.LookAboveTheClouds() 
}
```

in other words there's no way the compiler can guarantee that you can safely use your `IEnumerable<Animal>` as an `IEnumerable<Giraf>`. All girafs are animals but not all animals are girafs

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your problem here. When using `IEnumerable` you can't insert, and that is not what you are doing. What you are trying to do is assigning a `IEnumerable<string>` a value of `IEnumerable<object>` and that won't work. When you are assigning your `IEnumerable<string>` with an object that is of type `IEnumerble<object>` you can't guarantee that all the objects in the list is of type string. That is why can't do that.

Covariant, the `out` keyword, interfaces ensures that the output can always be understood by the consuming part, that is, an `IEnumerable<string>` can be casted to a list of `IEnumerable<object>` since `string : object` and someone consuming a list of `object` must know how to handle a `string` but not the other way around.

Contravariant, the `in` keyword, interfaces enables you to cast objects to less specified generics, that is, `IComparer<object>` can be casted to `IComparer<string>` since a class implementing `IComparer<object>` must now how to handle `string` since it is contravariant but not the other way around.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think it's strictly realted to type safity: what if you in your list
`IEnumerable<object> {"Hello", 2.34d, new MyCoolObject(), enumvalue}` ?

How runtime should treat those conversions ?

In case of `string` it could be a simple case, cause it *should* be enough to call override (if any) of `ToString()` , but framework designer can not rely on custom cases and should provide generic solutions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi , object can contain ANYTHING , so if i write something like  `IEnumerable<string> strings = objects` i want to do something like (psuedo) `strings[0]="lala"` so where is the problem, what do i care whats in Objects ??? I only want to insert Strings ! .....:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I wrote in my answer, that for string it *may be* even could be done, but framewrok designer can not add a feature only for *one, specific case*. What if instead of IEnumerable<string> you want to convert to IEnumerable<double> ? Hope I'm explained.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you cannot use IEnumerable to modify a collection.

The compiler will not allow code like the one below due to type safety issues as the one you mentioned (inserting int to an list of string) because you  can modify the strings lists here using objects

IEnumerable is simply an iterator over a collection.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    IList<object> objects = strings;  ** // This will give an error because compiler does not want you to do the line below **
    objects.Add(5);  // Type safety violated for IList<string> hence not allowed


    // The code below works fine as you cannot modify the strings collection using IEnumerable of object
    //IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    //IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign `IEnumerable<Parent>` to `IEnumerable<Child>` because it may contain elements that are **not** `Child`.

> but what about if i want to use the IEnumerable as insertion? something like :

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = ...;
IEnumerable<string> strings = objects
```

There is no way to know **at compile time** that the `IEnumerable<object>` doesn't contain a non-`string`. However, if you (the programmer) know there are only `string`s there, you can do the casting at run-time:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = objects.Cast<string>();
```

Incidentally, you might want to take a look at [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/covariance/info) of the tag [covariance](/questions/tagged/covariance).