# How to assign parent reference to a property in a child with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to find a way of configuring AutoMapper to set a property in a destination object with a reference of its source parent object. The code below shows what I'm trying to achieve. I'm moving data into the Parent & Child instances from the data objects. The mapping works fine to create the List collection with correct data but I need to have a ForEach to assign the parent instance reference.

```
public class ParentChildMapper
{
    public void MapData(ParentData parentData)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ParentData, Parent>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ChildData, Child>();

        //Populates both the Parent & List of Child objects:
        var parent = Mapper.Map<ParentData, Parent>(parentData);

        //Is there a way of doing this in AutoMapper?
        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
        {
            child.Parent = parent;
        }

        //do other stuff with parent
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public virtual string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentData
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use AfterMap.  Something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentData, Parent>()
    .AfterMap((s,d) => {
        foreach(var c in d.Children)
            c.Parent = d;
        });
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a loop altogether but your answer seems to be the only alternative. Something like: .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src)) was what I was looking for but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping for something different as well.  This gets pretty ugly if you have > 1 child list you need to process.

Comment: I know it's an old question and answer, but you could use some (more) Linq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less verbose

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
  .AfterMap((_, dest) => dest.Children.ForEach(x => x.Parent = dest))
```

[AfterMap](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html)

> Execute a custom function to the source and/or destination types after
>   member mapping

For completeness, this sort of thing should not really be a concern of automapper, as it leads to overly abstracted side effects.