# Access each element in a list inside a where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a customer List and a string List where each string is like "blah;huhu";

I want to get all customers whose name is in the last part of the splitted "blah;huhu"

like `c.Name == "huhu"`.

Thats my pseudo code:

String ID = 1000;

```
var query = customerListWithIdAndName.Where(
    c => c.Name == stringListWith2SemicolonSeparatedStrings.Split().Last()
);
```

What would be the correct code that I can make a comparison on EACH splitted value?

UPDATE:

I want for every returned customer to assign a value: String ID = 1000; Thus every customer returned must have the id 1000.

Comment: you want *I want to get all customers whose name is in the last part of the splitted "blah;huhu"* and *What would be the correct code that I can make a comparison on EACH splitted value*? that's confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I get what you want, this should do it:

```
var query = customerListWithIdAndName.Where(c =>
   stringListWith2SemicolonSeparatedStrings.Any(
       p => p.Split().Last() == c.Name));
```

Comment: he wants to compare name with the last splitted value i.e last string after last ;

Comment: I mean what wants to achieve by 'What would be the correct code that I can make a comparison on EACH splitted value?'

Comment: Op : I want to get all customers whose name is in the last part of the splitted "blah;huhu"

Comment: Yeah, but that's what the original code already does. In that case, the final question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Sandor sorry, the stringListWith2SemicolonSeparatedStrings is a String Array not List. Your code does not work. Split on a stringList cant work.

Comment: @Sandor ok that works fine there is still one minor thing which I updated in my question and I hope it does not make the first solution obsolete ;-). See my init question.

Comment: ok this helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq