# List<T>.ForEach() set property, return IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

The LINQ extension List.ForEach() doesn't return anything (void), but I would like to assign a property value to all objects in a list and then return some of them as IEnumerable.

e.g.

```
return myCollection
     .ForEach(x => x.ToBeDetermined = determine(x))
     .Where(x => x.ToBeTermined == true);
```

Comment: See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq

Comment: Just FYI, `ForEach` is in fact not a LINQ extension but a method in `List<T>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return myCollection
     .Select(x => {
                  x.ToBeDetermined = determine(x);
                  return x;
             })
     .Where(x => x.ToBeTermined == true);
```

Comment: Property assignment with .Select(). How beautiful.. but how do Frameworks like LINQ2SQL react on this?

Comment: @Acrotygma so I'm sure you never use `Convert.ToInt32()` in linq to object, because it doesn't work in linq to entities. Neither `ToString()` . Not a fan of assignments in linq, but this one is still readable.

Comment: @Acrotygma it all depends what myCollection is. If its an IQueryable then you might face some difficulties within "determine" method. But the solution would be to do .ToList() prior to .Select()

Comment: @Dimitri - do not use .ToList() for that - use .AsEnumerable() instead

Answer (score 3):

Since you are setting a Boolean property and then filtering on it you can use this syntax:

```
return myCollection.Where(x => x.ToBeTermined = determine(x));
```

Note that you should at least write an explicit comment in the code because most people will see this as a typo and will be willing to "fix".

Comment: No one ever wants to look at my code because of all my famous 'do-100-things-in-one-line-of-code' snippets. :(

Answer (score 1):

As an extension method, also making it more readable than other solutions (and also reusable):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
    return source;
}
```

Which makes the usage exactly as you had it in your original question:

```
return myCollection.ForEachEx(x => x.ToBeDetermined = determine(x))
                   .Where(x => x.ToBeTermined == true);
```

The differences from the original `ForEach` are:

1. Returns `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `void`.
2. Works for every `IEnumerable<T>` and not just `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

```
myCollection.ForEach(x => x.ToBeDetermined = determine(x));
return myCollection.Where(x => x.ToBeTermined == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return myCollection.Where(determine).Select(x => { x.ToBeDetermined = true; return x; });
```

Comment: this does not have the same semantics - if the previous value was `true`, this will not update the list with the new value `false`.