# Why can ToList modify original value without reassigning to itself?

Tags: c#, linq

I had seen this question [Update all objects in a collection using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq/399073#399073).

**class**

```
public class A
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

**sample data**

```
var arr1 = new List<A>()
{
    new A() {B = 10},
    new A() {B = 20}
};


var arr2 = new List<A>()
{
    new A() {B = 10},
    new A() {B = 20}
};

arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList();
arr2.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;});
arr2.ToList();
```

**Result**

```
arr1 <===============>
0
0
arr2 <===============>
10
20
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/71fNtW)

**My question**

Why does `arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList();` set `arr1` value without reassigning to `arr1` like

```
arr = arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList();
```

but `arr2` can't do the same thing using the following code

```
arr2.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;});
arr2.ToList();
```

I know it might be a *Lazy Evaluation*

But I want to know is there any official link or more elaborate explanation for this question?

Comment: Your `arr2` example would do the same thing, if you would apply/call `ToList()` on the result of `arr2.Select(...)` (currently you discard that result and call ToList on arr2 instead). Note that the lambda expression in the `Select` clause will only be evaluated (executed) by the `ToList` method in your example, not the Select clause itself. And by the way, neither of your examples modifies arr1 or arr2. Both lists remain unchanged. What changes is only the content of the elements of the lists, not the content of the lists themselves...

Comment: Until you iterate the source, the `Select` will not execute.

Comment: It's like calling `someString.Replace('a', 'b');` without assigning it to anything. `Replace` returns a new `string` but it goes nowhere unless it's assigned, as in `var newString = someString.Replace('a', 'b');`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to know why can `arr1` modify `B` property value only by `arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList();`?

Comment: You should **never use this technique**. A select should **never** mutate anything. If you want to mutate a collection, use *foreach*.

Comment: @EricLippert I know I won't use this in my real project. But I am curious how did it make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title says "...without reassigning to itself...": Because `A` is a reference type, `Select()` doesn't create copies of the items in the source collection. Your lambda gets each actual object in turn. When it sets `x.B = 0`, it's acting on the original item that's still in the collection.

The more interesting question is why the `arr1` and the `arr2` code behave differently.

Let's take a look at what `Select()` returns:

```
var z = arr2.Select(x => { x.B = 0; return x; });
arr2.ToList();
```

Set a breakpoint on the second line there, and we find that this is type of `z`; this is the thing that is returned by `arr2.Select(x => { x.B = 0; return x; })`. It's the same type of object you're calling `ToList()` on in the `arr1` line:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator<ConsoleApp3.A, ConsoleApp3.A>
```

Select() doesn't do much. It returns an object that's *prepared* to iterate over each item in `arr2` in turn, set the `B` property of each item, and then return each item in turn.

It's *ready* to do that. But it hasn't done it, and it won't do it until you ask it to (lazy evaluation, as you suggest). Let's try this:

```
var a = z.First();
```

That tells the `SelectListIterator` to evaluate the `Select()` lambda for just the first item in `arr2`. That's all it does. Now the first item in `arr2` has `B == 0`, but the rest don't, because you didn't touch them yet. So let's touch all of them:

```
var b = z.ToList();
```

Now the ToList() call will force the SelectListIterator to go through and execute your Select() lambda expression for every item in `arr2`. You did that right away for `arr1`, which is why `B` was zero for every item in `arr1`. You never did it for `arr2` in your code at all. The thing that does the work is not the `Select()`, but the object *returned by* `Select()`. For `arr2`, you discarded that object without enumerating it, so it never did the work.

And we now understand that `arr2.ToList()` didn't do anything: In the case of `arr1`, t was the act of calling `ToList()` on the result of the `Select()` that applied the `Select()`'s changes to `arr1`. If you had called `arr1.ToList();` instead, that would have had no effect either. It would just create an exact copy of `arr1`, and if you didn't assign that to anything, it would just be discarded.

All of this is one reason why we never put side effects in LINQ expressions: You create effects which are baffling even in a minimal, highly simplified example created for a StackOverflow question. You don't need that in production code.

Another reason is we never need to.

Comment: Thank for your reply. 
I think the key point is `Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator` class , there is a `MoveNext` method in source code tell me the question answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList(); //Enumerates the Select, so it is executed
arr2.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}); //Creates the query, it is not executed
arr2.ToList(); //Enumerates the list you already have
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is causing side effects in your select, that is instead of selecting data, you are assigning data "within" the select.

When you do this that code (the code that changes the data) gets executed whenever the collection gets enumerated, however neither arr1 nor arr2 are the collections getting enumerated here :

```
// Here arr1 is not getting enumerated, what is getting enumerated is what 
// is returned by the select, and it is enumerated immdiately because the 
// ToList materializes it. This means that while the collection arr1 is 
// unchanged, you are changing the value of its members, hence why it shows in 
// your further console writelines
arr1.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;}).ToList(); 

// here you have the same select, but you discard it! a select doesn't affect 
// the collection at all, arr2 is the SAME before and after the select, you 
// would have to call ToList on what was RETURNED by the select, which is why 
// it worked on arr1 (because you chained the ToList, so it was applied to 
// what was returned by the Select)
arr2.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;});

// This does strictly nothing, you create a new list from arr2, which you do 
// not store
// arr2.ToList();
```

Basically if you wanted to split the query for arr2 you would have to write it as such:
   var tmp = arr2.Select(x=>{x.B=0;return x;});
   tpm.ToList(); // call it on TMP not on arr2! arr2 was NOT changed, but tmp is what was returned by the select!

Also note that overall, you should NEVER do any of this, if you want to change every element of a collection, use a foreach, linq is there to shape and select data, not to modify it.