# Update the property of list items without "loop" and "if"

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

I am updating the property of the `list` items.

```
class Response
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to update the `Order` of a `List<Response>` variable. As of now, I am looping through each item of the list and updating it.

```
List<Response> data = FromDb();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    if(item.Name.Equals("A"))
    {
       item.Order=1;
    }
    if(item.Name.Equals("B"))
    {
       item.Order=2;
    }
    //Like this I have arround 20 conditions
}
```

The above code is working fine, but the problem is the `Cognitive Complexity` of the method is more than the allowed.

I tried something like below

```
data.FirstOrDefault(x => x..Equals("A")).Order = 1;
data.FirstOrDefault(x => x..Equals("B")).Order = 2;
//and more ...
```

In this code also `null` check is not in place, So if the searching string is not present in the list then again it will break.

If I add `null` check condition then again the `complexity` getting higher.

So here I want without any `for loop` or `if`, If I can update the Order of the list by using `linq`/`lamda` or anything else.

Comment: There will always be a `for` loop somewhere if you are working with multiple items. LINQ does not mutate objects, so while you might be able to do that it won't be idiomatic.

Comment: `Dictionary` looks more natural than `List` in this case, if you need to search by key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update all objects in a collection using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq)

Comment: I don’t know the purpose of that Response class but is it okay to use Enum for your Name attribute so that you can have order automatically if you start your Enum with A which have value of 1?

Comment: @Lucifer. I went to this link sometimes back, I am unable to add any condition with the answer which is my primary requirement.

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet. the return type of the method is the list of response and even some other properties are part of that response class.

Comment: @TufanChand Are indicies of Order somewhat permanent. I mean does A always mean Order 1, B Order 2 on so on. In other words is the alphabetical number connected with index or you can have name "G" for example with order "948423"?

Comment: @Leron_says_get_back_Monica. The Name and Order combinations are permanent, but not related with any index the value "A", "B" I just have given for demo purpose the real values are different

Comment: @TufanChand, does this order value comes from DB or a static value? If it comes from DB, you can join with the Order list.

Comment: @SelvaS. "Order" is not from DB. Only the Names are coming from DB.

Comment: @TufanChand Then Dictionary makes the most sense. `Dictionary<string, int> indexByName = new Dictionary<string, int> () { {"A", 1}, {"B", 2}}` and so on. Then `foreach (var item in data) { item.Order = indexByName[item.Name] }`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you measure `Cognitive Complexity` and how much of it is allowed to be pushed out into other functions, but something like this makes the ordering quite declarative?

```
[Fact]
public void TestIt()
{
    var data = FromDb().Select(SetOrder(
        ("A", 1),
        ("B", 2)
    ));
}

static Func<Response, Response> SetOrder(params (string Name, int Order)[] orders)
{
    var orderByKey = orders.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

    return response =>
    {
        if (orderByKey.TryGetValue(response.Name, out var result))
            response.Order = result.Order;

        return response;
    };
}
```

**Addendum in response to comment:**

In order to have a default value for unmatched names, the SetOrder could be changed to this:

```
static Func<Response, Response> SetOrder(params (string Name, int Order)[] orders)
{
    var orderByKey = orders.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

    return response =>
    {
        response.Order = 
            orderByKey.TryGetValue(response.Name, out var result)
                ? result.Order
                : int.MaxValue;

        return response;
    };
}
```

Comment: If I want to set a default order which is not in my static list. For example, if Name="Z" came from DB and I don't have any static order for this text So I want to assign a very higher Order like 9999 so that it will come at last of the list.