# LINQ : make select and update

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have this code

```
foreach (MyType o in myList)
{
    var res = from p in myOriginalList
              where p.PropertyA == o.PropertyA && p.PropertyB == o.PropertyB
              select p;

    //Need to update myOriginalList

    //....
}
```

I'd like in the myOriginalList do an update for each record found by the Linq select. How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in res)
{
   item.prop = updatedvalue;
}
```

Do you mean this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt `ForEach` extension - so just loop and update:

```
foreach(var item in res) {
    item.SomeProp = someValue;
}
```

Note also that you can use `SelectMany` to do this in one query:

```
var res = from MyType o in myList
          from p in myOriginalList
              where p.PropertyA == o.PropertyA && p.PropertyB == o.PropertyB
              select p;
```

Comment: To be nitpicky, there is a ForEach extension, but not directly on the IEnumerable interface but on the generic List (philosophic reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800151/why-is-foreach-on-ilistt-and-not-on-ienumerablet/1296774#1296774)

Comment: in the first part, you update the result of the query not "myOriginalList" right ? it's an update of the original based on the res result I need

Comment: @Kris-I; it depends on what you are trying to do. Normally when people say "update the list" they mean "update the state of the objects that are referenced by the list", i.e. "item.SomeProp = someValue;". Unless you are using `struct`s. Do you mean to *swap* items in the list? i.e. change the actual reference?