# Execute Action<T> by IEnumerable Characteristics?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, action

I have this code :

```
 int[] g = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
 g.ToList().ForEach(f=>Console.Write(f));
```

For each item in the array   , I want to execute an `Action`....

`int[]` is **already** implementing `Ienumerable`.

I would like to execute an Action without   "`ToList()`"

is there any other solution ( with **one** line of code) to do it  ( without toList? i.e using its `IEnumerable` characteristics )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is .ForEach() on IList<T> and not on IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800151/why-is-foreach-on-ilistt-and-not-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [LINQ equivalent of foreach for IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Array.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) instead:

```
Array.ForEach(g, f => Console.Write(f));
```

or even<sup>1</sup>:

```
Array.ForEach(g, Console.Write);
```

Personally I'd probably use a `foreach` loop instead though, for the [reasons given by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)...

---

<sup>1</sup> If it compiles. I've given up trying to predict whether method group conversion will work in the context of generic type inference.

Comment: Oh, so it's available on `Array` as well! I never did realize this.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, but only via a *static* method as opposed to the *instance* method in `List<T>`

Comment: See my answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach()` is a method in the `List` class, not the `IEnumerable` interface, so it would not be available to the array directly.

If you are hardcore about doing it one line of code and `IEnumerable`, you could use (or abuse) a method like `Any()` or `All()` and do your desired operation (in this case, printing) before returning an appropriate value that would cause the iteration to continue.

Or you could instead use `Array.ForEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Jon Skeet, here's a useful extension method that I wrote:

Client:

```
var jobs = new List<Job>() 
    { 
        new Job { Id = "XAML Developer" }, 
        new Job { Id = "Assassin" }, 
        new Job { Id = "Narco Trafficker" }
    };
jobs.Execute(ApplyFilter, j => j.Id);

public void ApplyFilter(string filterId) { }
```

Extension Method:

```
    public static void Execute<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TKey> applyBehavior, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var target = keySelector(item);
            applyBehavior(target);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure that the key selector is worth it - after all, you can always use `jobs.Select(j => j.Id).Execute(ApplyFilter)` without it.