# Why ForEach extension method is not available in ObservableCollections in C#

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

Why ForEach extension method is not available in ObservableCollections class while it is available in List ?

Comment: As it's more of a design issue question, I think it's closer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800151/why-is-foreach-on-ilistt-and-not-on-ienumerablet

Answer (score 6):

As JJohn says, it's by design. Read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) by Eric Lippert for more information. A standard `foreach` loop works just as well and is generally more readable.

Answer (score 2):

`ForEach` is available only in `List<T>` and not in any other collection. It is just design decision.

Comment: Don't you think this is a common function and this function must have been in this class. I doubt, there must be performance related issue.

Comment: Its not that its available only in List<T>. You can implement you own class which implements IEnumerable and you will get ForEach functionality in your class's objects.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach can be used only on those objects which are of classes that implements IEnumerable. 
IEnumerable is an interface that defines one method GetEnumerator which returns an IEnumerator interface, this in turn allows readonly access to a collection. A collection that implements IEnumerable can be used with a foreach statement.