# In LINQ to objects, how to set an object property to null if it equals "folder"?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of objects representing a folder structure.

I'd like to set the property `FileExtension` to null, if it's a folder.

This is as far as I've got.  Can anyone help?

```
var items = MyClass.All().ToList();
items.ForEach(x => x.FileExtension = string.empty)
     .Where(y => y.FileExtension == "folder")
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
items
  .Where(i => i.FileExtension == "folder")
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i => i.FileExtension = null);
```

Comment: I was trying to use just linq - so perfect!

Thank you

Comment: To be picky, ToList() is not linq; it's a generics list method. Still, this seems to be an acceptable way to do it, even with the crowd that argues against having a foreach in linq. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200574/linq-equivalent-of-foreach-for-ienumerablet, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface. The cleanest with no side-effects tends to be the good ol' foreach loop, as with @TcKs answer.

Comment: More picky: System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList  <-- if it "is not Linq", why's it in a Linq namespace, huh huh?

Comment: Shoot, sorry, miswrote - and yes, since I was being picky - it's the ForEach that's not linq, it's a generics list method. That's what I meant, yeah, that.

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(var item in items.Where( i => i.FileExtension == "folder" ))
    item.FileExtension = null;
```