# Why is ForEach Method only on the List<T> collection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

First, let me specify I am refering to the `List<T>` method and not the C# keyword.  What would be Microsoft's reasoning for having the Foreach method on the `List<T>` collection but no other collection/enumerable type, specifically `IEnumerable<T>`?

I just discovered this method the other day, and found it to be very nice syntax for replacing traditional foreach loops that only perform one or 2 lines of methods on each object.

It seems like it would be fairly trivial to create an extension method that ,performs this same function.  I guess I'm looking at why MS made this decision and based on that if I should just make an extension method.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked when creating the question, but didn't see the dup.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/) has responded to this question numerous times, including [on his blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).

His response has been that `ForEach()` is something you use explicitly for its side effects - whereas LINQ is largely intended to be a side-effect free API to define projections and manipulations on sequences.

Outside of uses like [parallel loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28VS.100%29.aspx), the functional `ForEach` syntax doesn't add much in the way of expressive power, and it is slightly less efficient than a regular `foreach` loop due to the delegate invocations.

If you really, really want a `ForEach` for `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not hard to write one:

```
public static class ForEachExtension
{
    public static void ForEach<T>( this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> action )
    {
        foreach( var item in seq ) 
            action( item );
    }

    // Here's a lazy, streaming version:
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachLazy<T>( this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> action )
    {
        foreach( var item in seq )
        {
            action( item );
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - ForEach() on an IEnumerable has more cons than pros

Comment: Also, use Select. It accomplishes nearly the same thing in a LINQ-ish way :)

Comment: Like `.Select(t => { sideeffect(); return t})`?

Answer (score 6):

Read the answer from the man who helped design the compiler .. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The wrote this prior to extension methods - it was added in .NET 2.0.  At the time, there was no way to add this as an extension to any enumerable - it would have to be part of the interface (which I agree doesn't necessarily fit, since enumerables **can** be infinitely long, and this would be bad).

I believe that, when C# 3 was released, they probably felt that LINQ, via Select, privided an easy alternative, while being more clear about side-effects.  [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) on the subject describes the side-effects, and rationale behind why you'd use ForEach vs. foreach in more detail, as well.

Answer (score 1):

To crib an answer from [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/default.aspx) (who was cribbed from Eric Gunnerson):

> [Every feature starts off at -100 points.](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)

Basically, somebody would have to write it and by so doing take time away from some other feature.  Since you can create `ForEach()` yourself trivially it would never take precedence over other, less trivial features.

Plus `ForEach()` predates extension methods.