# Selecting ListBox values against a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list:

```
var _books = new List<int> {233,5,20};
```

And a ListBox with a lot of books (their value is an item id)

How do I take this working code:

```
var t = from ListItem n in lbBooks.Items 
                    where _books.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)) 
                    select n;
            foreach(ListItem i in t)
            {
                i.Selected = true;
            }
```

and convert it to lambda:

```
lbBooks.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(n => _books.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)))
                .Select(n => n.Selected = true);
```

Comment: I forgot about LINQ's foreach. :/

Comment: what? There is no foreach in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option? Don't. LINQ queries are supposed to be just that – queries. And queries aren't supposed to have side effects. Your approach using `foreach` is perfectly fine.

If you really wanted, you could create your own extension method `ForEach()`, similar to the one on `List<T>`, but I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your not far off, you need to return the whole object and set Selected to true. Something like:

```
lbBooks.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(n => _books.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)))
                .Select(n => SetSelected(n));
```

The above .Select can be shortend to `.Select(SetSelected);` if you prefer

```
private ListItem SetSelected(ListItem listItem)
{
    listItem.Selected = true;
    return listItem
}
```

Additionally to save casting you could utilise the SetSelected to handle your casting once you have just the records you want. Your query would then become:

```
lbBooks.Items.Where(n => _books.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)))
             .Select(n => SetSelected(n));

private ListItem SetSelected(Item item)
{
    ListItem result = item as ListItem;
    result.Selected = true;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do it using as short and concise syntax as possible, see my answer above.

Comment: Ok. That works to. Personally I prefer a more readable solution but i guess it's horses for courses

Comment: what is your opinion on using your last code example vs a foreach loop?

Comment: As Magnus mentions, its means you are iterating over the collection twice.  The above will only get your collection once and build a list item from that result. If it were me i wouldn't use the ForEach approach (but I'm biased)

Comment: I meant the the foreach example in my first code example, not the List class foreach extension. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: The response applies to both.  In either case your iterating through a collection once more than you need to

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `.ToList()` and use the `ForEach' operator as so:

```
lbBooks.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
             .Where(n => _books.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)))
             .Select(n => n).ToList().ForEach(n=> n.Selected=true);
```

Comment: That would mean one extra unnecessary iteration of the collection

Comment: ` .Select(n => n.Selected = true);` doesn't work, please explain that.

Comment: `Select` returns a value, but you want an action.

Comment: @Magnus, my Tolist().Foreach is doing the same thing as creating a foreach block and it's cleaner. I don't understand why you downvote.

Comment: You iterate all the values to add them to a list, then you iterate them again to set the selected value, that's totally unnecessary. O(2n)

Comment: Also you shuld use a `join` instead if contains for better performance as joins uses `HashSets` internally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [build in ForEach extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface). You can create your own, but I do not see any problem with the code you have.

Comment: I'm not sure that is 100% correct, if you convert the IEnumerable to a list, you can foreach off the list. Also i'm not sure why my lambda example doesn't work.

Comment: The `ForEach` you are using is not an extension method to IEnumerable, but belongs to `List<T>`.