# How do I write a for each lambda expression to iterate over a numeric range in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to write something like:

(0 .. 7).ForEach(i => SomeMethod(i))

but either I can't find the correct syntax, or this isn't possible in C#. If it can be done, what is the correct syntax please?

Comment: Many thanks to everyone for such a fast response to this question! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you're after, you'll need to add the illusive and well-known LINQ `ForEach` statement.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ForEach(i => SomeMethod(i));

Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ForEach(i => 
{
    string oddEven = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is {1}", i, oddEven));
}
```

**Extra reading**

["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Add usage example for becoming the perfect answer.

Comment: I like this solution. It just seems odd to me that the framework doesn't already include this extension method. Guess I'd better read the "foreach" vs "ForEach" article to learn more.

Comment: Here's the rationale why it is not included, and why it should not be included:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @DavidArno: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface

Comment: At the core of it all, the argument against it is "the purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect". With this in mind, I tend to only use the `ForEach` expression where the items won't be effected, but instead are used in a computation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Enumerable.Range Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 7)) SomeMethod(i);
```

And if you add ForEach extension method as @Richard suggested, just do:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ForEach(SomeMethod);
```

Comment: Using method group is a great suggestion. I was wondering which solution I preferred, but now there's no question that I like better the extension method approach.

Comment: I'm with Yorye: this answer's worth an upvote, but I prefer Richard's solution.

Comment: agreed, I'm personally have ForEach extension method in my projects, but it is not in BCL, so I didn't suggested it at first. but I also upvoted Richard's solution

Comment: +1 I prefer this solution, this is not a lambda-happy solution. You can just merely pass the SomeMethod's address. Others, upon discovering lambda, will do it like this, a tautology: `Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ToList().ForEach(x => SomeMethod(x))` They are forgetting that it could be done simpler(just pass the method's address). You could prune that lambda and *just pass* the method's address instead `Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ToList().ForEach(SomeMethod)`

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ToList().ForEach(i => whatever)`

You need `ToList`, because pure `IEnumerable` doesn't have `ForEach`. (Well, you can easily define your own if you need one.)

Or maybe `Enumerable.Range(0, 7 + 1)`, if you want including 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Enumerable.Range();`