# Difference between "foreach" and extension method: ForEach

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, extension-methods

Could anyone point out the differences between `C#` statements and their alike extension methods? e.g: `foreach` vs. `.ForEach`(the extension method).

If there are **any** difference, what are they? Security wise? Performance wise? Which one is better to use? Which one is safer? etc.

And if there are no differences, then why bother writing them?

I've been thinking and searching a bit about this question if mine and didn't find my answer.

Comment: [Eric Lippert's blog: “foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)

Comment: Note that tehre isn't a "ForEach" extension method *in the framework* - the closest is `List<T>.ForEach` (which was removed from the Windows Store API)

Comment: Can't really get a better explanation than from the man himself.

Comment: I've seen the question mentioned above. But my question about thing like: loading time, performance, security, "side-effects" (which @Kane mentioned) still remain unanswered.

Comment: "if there are no differences, then why bother writing them?" An excellent question! I wish I had a good answer.

Comment: @KiaPanahi, what other information would you like to see? It's somewhat difficult to expand more on "it's pretty much the same, minus some very minor things." If you point me in the right direction, I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the extension method you use. Internally, there's really nothing special about most's version of .ForEach.

There would be minimal/negligable time to load the extension method at app load and compile time. There "May" be minimal overhead to convert the .ForEach syntax into the underlying foreach as it's technically only a wrapper.  It could potentially cause security issues, but only because it can create closure sitiuations where your objects may not be collected at the time expected (eg: held in scope longer).  Ultimately, there's very, very little difference, and it comes down to taste. Unless of course, you're trying to shave off every millisecond, and in that case, using the native body is the best way to go.

I would like to mention that the .ForEach strikes against the premise of using lambda statements being purely functional, that is, it breaks the "functional" style and introduces the possibility of side-effects.  Using a foreach body makes the code more readable, and explicit.

Please see:
[Why there is no ForEach extension method on IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface?rq=1)

It's a trade off.  The extension method is certainly more concise, and it provides compile time checking.  The extension method also can introduce difficulty of readability, difficulty of maintainability, and side-effects.

Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

> The second reason is that doing so adds zero new representational
>   power to the language. Doing this lets you rewrite this perfectly
>   clear code:
>
> foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
>
> into this code:
>
> foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });
>
> which uses almost exactly the same characters in slightly different
>   order. And yet the second version is harder to understand, harder to
>   debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing
>   object lifetimes in subtle ways.

Comment: There is no premise of purity in the lambda syntax.

Comment: @Lee, purity in the sense of of "Purely functional". I'll make that edit.

Comment: I'm saying lambdas are not 'purely functional', they are a short-hand for anonymous methods and hence allow side effects. Linq itself promotes purity, and it is often used with lambdas, but lambdas themselves do not.

Comment: @Lee, I have to concede as you are correct. However, this is the spirit behind the decision of MS to not include this function in the standard library.  All the standard operators are intended to be used in a functional way, though you certainly can break that pattern if you wish.  I do wish to include this point, but I don't know how to revise without detracting from the point I was trying to make. Suggestions?

Comment: The "closure semantics" is indeed a very important detail! As for the rest, I disagree. `foreach` is always superior (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The provided answers are inaccurate. There are many pitfalls when using a `ForEach` extension method. E.g. the following extension method may easily become a performance killer:

```cs
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

And then we misuse it:

```cs
IEnumerable<T> items = new List<T>();
items.ForEach(UpdateItem);
```

Looks nice, right? Well, here the `ForEach()` extension method is called on an `IEnumerable<T>` which means the compiler is forced to *allocate* a generic enumerator instead of using an optimized, allocation-free [version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,569). Then, the `Action` argument calls for another quite heavy [delegate allocation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/know-thine-implicit-allocations/). Put this loop on a hot path and the `Garbage Collector` will go nuts, causing significant performance issues.

Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62663221/419761), where I explain this in much greater detail.

In terms of security, I have seen developers accidentally including a third-party assembly to use a specific `ForEach()` extension method. This implied shipping an unwanted dependency from who-knows-where with unknown capabilities.

### Summary

- `foreach` is safer.
- `foreach` is more performant.
- `foreach` is better. The compiler knows exactly how to deal with it efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

`.ForEach` is similar to `Parallel.ForEach`.  I've seen the regular `.ForEach` used to develop/debug parallel versions before.  Whats nice about it is that you don't have to change a bunch of code to move between the two.

In general, if I have no intentions to do the `Parallel.ForEach`, then I prefer the regular `foreach` for readability.