# Scan nested dictionary with LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this working code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Example {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var files = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>()
                   { { "file1", new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "A", 1 } } } };
        foreach(var file in files) {
            File.WriteAllLines(file.Key + ".txt", file.Value.Select(
                    item => item.Key + item.Value.ToString("000")).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to change the `foreach` to LINQ syntax. Nothing I already tried worked.

Comment: Yor question title and body are not related. More information is needed if you wish someone to help you. For example show statement where nested dictionary cannot be infered

Comment: @Edin Sorry, I change the question when I was writing because what I gave tried certainly was very wrong.

Comment: For each is appropriate here - your code is strictly side effect based which is generally not what you use functional methods for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understand that, but I'm trying to learn how to do in other ways.

Comment: @bigown trying to use LINQ here is learning how to do this in *wrong* way. You already have a collection, and now you want to perform some action for each item in that collection. That's what `foreach` loop is for.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Learn the wrong way is learning too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
var files = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>() 
            { { "file1", new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "A", 1 } } } };
files.ForEach(kvp =>
    File.WriteAllLines(kvp.Key + ".txt", kvp.Value.Select(
            item => item.Key + item.Value.ToString("000")).ToArray()));
```

As per Alexei's comment, `IEnumerable.ForEach` isn't a standard extension method as it implies mutation, which isn't the aim of functional programming. You can add it with a helper method [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200584/314291):

```
public static void ForEach<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
        action(element);
}
```

Also, your original title implied that the initializer syntax for Dictionaries is unwieldy. What you can do to reduce the amount of typing / code real estate for a large number of elements is to build up an array of anonymous objects and then `ToDictionary()`. Unfortunately there is a small performance impact:

```
var files = new [] { new { key = "file1", 
                           value = new [] { new {key = "A", value = 1 } } } }
    .ToDictionary(
        _ => _.key, 
        _ => _.value.ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried something like that without success. Your code generate this compiler error: `select.cs(12,19): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Apols - you need to roll your own extension method. I've updated.

Comment: I'm playing with that now, but I think this is the way. I probably will accept it later.

Comment: There is no difference between `foreach` and `ForEach` here... I can't see how it makes the solution better. And btw. there is already `ForEach` method defined on `List<T>`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek OP is iterating a dictionary

Comment: It's not about what kind of collection OP's iteration over. It's about the fact, that writing your own `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` is imo not a good idea and should not be done.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` is exactly what you should be using here. LINQ is all about querying data: projecting, filtering, sorting, grouping, etc. You're trying to execute an action for each element in collection which is already in there as you it.

**Just iterate using `foreach`.**

There are reasons why there is no `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

- [Why is there not a ForEach extension method on the IEnumerable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface)
- [Why I Don’t Use the ForEach Extension Method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/08/why-i-don-t-use-the-foreach-extension-method.aspx)

It's mostly about:

> The reason to not use `ForEach` is that it blurs the boundary between pure functional code and state-full imperative code.

The only reason I can see not to use `foreach` loop is when you want to make your actions run in parallel by using [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    files,
    kvp => File.WriteAllLines(kvp.Key + ".txt", kvp.Value.Select(
               item => item.Key + item.Value.ToString("000")).ToArray()));
```

Having `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` is a bad design and I advice against it.