# foreach vs LINQ .ForEach()

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Why does LINQ `.ForEach` require a `List` object, while the `foreach` statement only requires `IEnumerable`?

I prefer using `foreach` when having multiple lines and LINQ for single line statements - just for readability.

But what is preferred, and why? And why the difference?

Comment: ForEach doesnt belong to LINQ

Comment: The `foreach` doesn't even require IEnumerable. It uses duck typing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Linq `ForEach()` method. The method you are looking at is [a member of `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[See here for a discussion on why Linq/IEnumerable doesn't have `ForEach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface).