# Iterating an IEnumerable<T>. Best way?

Tags: c#

Looking to the implementation of the [method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,79de3e39e69a4811)

```
void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

in the List<> class (.NET Framework 4.5.2), I can see an iteration over a collection like this

```
using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
    while(en.MoveNext()) {
        Insert(index++, en.Current);                                    
    }                
}
```

I am wondering what could be the reason to prefer that syntax over this one

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    Insert(index++, item)
}
```

I have created an assembly with two methods each one using a different approach. Then, looking into the generated IL code, I can see both methods calling the Dispose method enforced by the implementation of the `IEnumerator<T>` and hence `IDisposable`.

So `IDisposable` is not the reason and here is my question.

Is there any reason to prefer one syntax vs the other, other than simple style(ish) preferences?

Comment: foreach basically behind the scenes enumerate the way you are seeing implementation,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**foreach is the recommended way** because you don't specify details about how you want to iterate over the enumeration. Also, you write less code and it's more readable.

Comment: I wonder why the .NET Framework Team did not use foreach in that implementation, though

Comment: the reason for it is that `IEnumerable` should not have side effects.

Comment: @jmelosegui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-is-there-not-a-foreach-extension-method-on-the-ienumerable-interface

Answer (score 3):

They're exactly equivalent, it's something called **syntactic sugar**. The only reason to use `foreach` is because it's shorter, less error prone, more readable etc.

You can chceck the article on `foreach` implementation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

for loops are faster than foreach loops. The difference is tiny now though, so it's usually not even worth considering. I think there was a bigger difference in earlier versions of .net.

Answer (score 0):

Any collection which inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` (an enumerable object) it can be enumerated using foreach loop.

Consider this example:

```
foreach(char c in "Ehsan")
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

It is bascially a high level way of iterating the `IEnumerable<T>` , if the enumerator implements `iDisposable` the `foreach` statement uses `using` statement and it implilctly will dispose the enumerator object.

At low level we can wrtie it :

```
using(var enumerator = "Ehsan".GetEnumerator())
{
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
       var element = enumerator.Current;
       Console.WriteLine(element);
    }

}
```

So the `foreach` is doing the work for you, you don't have to write like the above to enumerate the `IEnumeable<T>`