# For each get RowIndex

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, extension-methods

Is there a way in a for each to get the row index ?

Example :

```
int rowIndex = 0;
foreach (int a in numbers)
{
    // Manipulation
    rowIndex++;
}
```

What I would like to have

```
foreach (int a in numbers)
{
    a.RowIndex;
}
```

Is there a quick way of doing it ? Maybe with the use of extension methods ?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(C#) Get index of current foreach iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
foreach ( var item in numbers.Select( (x,i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })) {
  var index = item.Index;
  var value = item.Value;
  ...
}
```

There is an overload of select which passes down the index of the item.  This code will create a new anonymous type for every item which includes both the index and the value.

Here's an alternate way which makes the syntax slightly more readable.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T,int> del) {
  int i = 0;
  foreach ( var cur in source ) { 
    del(cur, i);
    i++;
  }
}

numbers.ForEach( (x,i) =>
{
  // x is the value and i is the index
}
```

This doesn't add a whole lot over the define a local and increment it manually solution.  Is there a particular reason you don't want to do it that way?

Comment: This does the job more in the style of the syntax the asker seems to want, though to me it seems a bit ugly, and not really adding extra value compared to incrementing a local value.

Comment: @Noldorin, I agree, but it's what the user asked for.  I'll add some qualifications

Comment: @JaredPar: Yes, indeed, the asker did seem to want something like that. Anyway, it's a good answer now with the alternative (slightly nicer) and the qualifications added.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way, if you're going to stick to a foreach loop. Nothing level, but I think it's the best way to go still.

```
int rowIndex = 0;
foreach (int a in numbers)
{
    rowIndex++; // You could of course inline this wherever rowIndex first
                // gets used, and then simply reference rowIndex (without
                // the increment) later.

    // ...
}
```

But once you start doing this, it's probably best just to use an ordinary for loop anyway (unless you can't because the collection only implements `IEnumerable` and not `IList`/`ICollection` of course).