# How can I know a row index while iterating with foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach

in the next example how can I know the current row index?

```
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
//this.text = temprow.INDEX????
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [(C#) Get index of current foreach iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a type in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which can help with this - `SmartEnumerable`. It's a dumb name, but it works :) See the [usage page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) for details, and if you're using C# 3 you can make it even simpler:

```
foreach (var item in temptable.Rows.AsSmartEnumerable())
{
    int index = item.Index;
    DataRow value = item.Value;
    bool isFirst = item.IsFirst;
    bool isLast = item.IsLast;
}
```

Comment: I assume that `temptable.Rows` is a DataTable, but when I try to do what you show in this code it tells me: _DataRowCollection "does not contain a definition for AsSmartEnumerable"_. So what kind of object is `temptable.Rows`? Help..

Comment: @J.Rodr&#237;guez Did you include MiscUtil in your project, and then add a using directive as per the usage page? Basically it should work with any `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Yes Jon, it's included. For a list if it works, I don't know why it doesn't allow it in `DataTable` Example: `List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in list.AsSmartEnumerable())`.

Comment: It should be noted that of its MiscUtil I am only using: `SmartEnumerable.cs` and `SmartEnumerableExt.cs`. I'm missing something else?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez My guess is that Rows only implements the non-generic interface. Use LINQ to call Cast and then call AsSmartEnumerable on the result.

Comment: This is the right thing `foreach (var item in temptable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsSmartEnumerable())` Thank's Jon

Answer (score 23):

You have to create one yourself

```
var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
    this.text = i;
    // etc
    i++;
}
```

or you can just do a for loop instead.

Comment: +1, though I would rarely (if ever) advocate a `for` instead of a `foreach`. Different storage mechanisms can perform very poorly on index-based lookups (a linked list, for instance) and very well on a straight enumeration.

Comment: @Adam Understandable, measuring is probably the best thing to figure out which way would be better.

Answer (score 16):

If you can use Linq, you can do it this way:

```
foreach (var pair in temptable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                   .Select((r, i) => new {Row = r, Index = i}))
{
    int index = pair.Index;
    DataRow row = pair.Row;
}
```

Comment: Man, I was just going to enter this response... oh well

Answer (score 6):

You actually Don't. One of the beauties with foreach is that you don't have the extra set of code handling incrementing and checks on the length.

If you want to have your own Index you would have to do something like this

```
int rowindex = 0;
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
//this.text = temprow.INDEX????
    this.text = rowindex++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int rowIndex = temptable.Rows.IndexOf(temprow);
```

Comment: I would advice against that. It would probably cost a lot more than using your own incrementer.

Comment: I set a breakpoint part way during a long running foreach loop while testing and used this in a watch window to help identify how much longer I had to go.  Good enough for debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with a standard foreach loop.  The simplest way is to use a for loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < temptable.Rows.Count; i++ ) {
  DataRow temprow = (DataRow)temptable.Rows[i];
  ...
}
```

Another option is to use an extension method

```
public static void ForEachIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T,int> del) {
  var i = 0; 
  foreach ( var cur in e ) {
    del(cur,i);
  }
}
```

...

```
temptable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>.ForEachIndex((cur,index) 
{
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there's a much faster way I think. No iteration required!
First, declare a static variable for the Friend RowID Field of the DataRow:

```
Private Shared RowIDFieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(DataRow).GetField("_rowID", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Then All you need to do to use it is:

```
RowIDFieldInfo.GetValue(MyDataRow) - 1
```

I have not tested this after resorting or filtering.
In my case I haven't a need to do that, so this works.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never...

```
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
    temptable.Rows.IndexOf(temprow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write any Cell number and get RowIndex

---

```
foreach (var item in datagridview.Rows)
   {
     //TextBox1.Text= item.Cells[0].RowIndex.ToString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a for-loop, or use an integer follow along:

```
int count =0;
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
    //count is the index of the row in the array temptable.Rows
    //this.text = temprow.INDEX????
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `for` loop to get the index

```
for(int i=0; i<temptable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var index = i;
   var row = temptable.Rows[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While LFSR's answer is right, I'm pretty sure calling .IndexOf on just about any collection/list is going to enumerate the list until it finds a the matching row.  For large DataTable's this could be slow.

It might be better to for (i = 0; i < temptable.Rows.Count; i++) { ... } over the table.  That way you have the index without imposing a find-the-index tax.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way to retrieve data by using index instead of using column name

```
foreach (DataRow temprow in temptable.Rows)
{
    String col1 = temprow[0].ToString().Trim();
    String col2 = temprow[1].ToString().Trim();
}
```

Hope it help