# Is it possible to increment the identifier in a foreach loop without evaluation of its expression?

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects that I would like to iterate through to ultimately recognize some type of pattern. Currently I have a bunch of if statements that checks a flag for the expression. For example I have something along the lines of if (!foundFirstObjectOfTypeA). Once I found the first object of type A I would set the flag to true and we would no longer execute the block and move on to the next block. I have several types of patterns to recognize and because of this it has created a large block of if statements that are hard to understand and ugly.

Is there a way to peek/look past the identifier without the evaluation of the expression in the foreach loop? If I could do something along the lines of if (identifer == ObjectA && identifer.next == ObjectB) it would make my code much more readable and understandable and I could deal without having to set flags.

If there is no direct method/way does someone have some clever workarounds to simulate the effects I desire?

Comment: You probably want to explicitly create an enumerator for the collection first ... GetEnumerator maybe? Good question!

Comment: Please don't put tags like "[C#]" in the title. Once in the tags is enough.

Comment: This sounds like either a state machine or a d-graph. If you are not familiar with those, it might help you to do some research, as their theory might help you to come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead to increment `i`, then just look at `object[i]` and `object[i+1]`. What type of collection are you using? A list? An array? All a `foreach` loop does is hide the counter from you. There's absolutely **no** reason to use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, if I understand your situation.

This should work for any list and any sequence of objects:

**Function:**

```
public static bool ContainsSequence
    (System.Collections.Generic.IList<object> list, params object[] seq)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count() - seq.Count() + 1; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < seq.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (list[i + j] != seq[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j == seq.Count())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var A = new object();
    var B = new object();
    var C = new object();
    var D = new object();

    var list = new[] {A, B, C, D};
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsSequence(list, B, C, D));
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsSequence(list, A, D, C, B, A, C));
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsSequence(list, A, B));
}
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
True
```

The function can be made simpler if you know how many objects you're looking for (if you're only looking for two, it's *almost* [Hamid Nazari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314657/c-is-it-possible-to-increment-the-identifier-in-a-foreach-loop-without-evaluat/3314681#3314681)'s answer - you just need to add *AndrewS*'s bound checking, below.)

If you want the *index* of the start of the sequence, you can change the return type of my function to an int and return `i` instead of `true` (and return `-1` instead of `false`.)

Comment: Yes - and remember to check within your for loop that you aren't on the last index otherwise object[i+1] with throw an error

Comment: *@Stuart* +1 - A good point that will only come up when you least expect it. (Unless you're *certain* you will always match the pattern *somewhere* in the list.)

Comment: use 'for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)' and you'd be safe.

Comment: This could definitely be made into an extension method for the generic list

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is direct support for it, but you can always emulate.

For example (part of a solution):

```
  static IEnumerable<Peekable<T>> ToPeekable(this IEnumerable<T> stream)
  {
     T prev = <get first item, and move...>
     foreach(T item in stream)
     {
       yield return new Peekable<T>(prev, item);
       prev = item;
    }
    yield return new Peekable<T>(item, default(T));
  }
```

Update: Missing parts

```
class Peekable<T>
{
    public Peekable(T current, T next)
    {
        Current = current;
        Next = next;
    }

    public T Current { get; private set; }
    public T Next { get; private set; }
}

static class PeekableAdaptor
{
    public static IEnumerable<Peekable<T>> ToPeekable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> stream)
    {
        var source = stream.GetEnumerator();

        if (!source.MoveNext()) 
            yield break;

        T prev = source.Current;

        while (source.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return new Peekable<T>(prev, source.Current);
            prev = source.Current;
        }

        yield return new Peekable<T>(prev, default(T));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var pair in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToPeekable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Current, pair.Next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is *way* too complicated for what the OP wants... I think a simple `for` loop would be better. Always try and use the simplest solution!

Comment: @sukru, please elaborate on how this works. @Daniel - a for loop will not always be available. Assume that you are working with a ... stream , which does not know how many things will come.

Comment: @Hamish - then a while loop would work just as well, wouldn't it? I simply think you should work with the information the OP gave - a collection, and a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen - please add code examples of both `for` and `while` to your answer that are somewhat realistic. Code talks louder than words, and Devil is in the details. If your samples do not make my eyes bleed, then they are Ok. I need to see them.

Comment: @Hamish - Code posted. A while solution would be slightly trickier, but work very similarly.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan I've added the complete implementation.

One WARNING though. For the last iteration default(T) might not always be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a for loop, you can do something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    if (list[i] == ObjectA && list[i + 1] == ObjectB)
        ; // Your code
```

Comment: The Capacity of a .Net List can be greater than its Count, and using list[i + 1] could cause an out of bounds exception.

'for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)' would be safer.

Comment: @Hamid - You're still missing the `- 1`, since you can never match the first object of a sequence with the last item of the list, and `Count` is a function, not a property, so you need parenthesis.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah you're right about the last item, but I beg to differ on `Count` being a function.

Comment: The Count() method is a member of the Linq Namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx. The Count Property is a member of the Generics Namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7f69ad7.aspx

Comment: If `list` is indeed a `List<T>` then it does have a `Count` property so the point of whether it is a property or a function would be moot. Of course, this answer and most others assume the OP was using an indexable collection which was never actually stated.

Comment: @Metro Smurf - You're right - and to be honest I *had* thought it was a property myself. It's odd that it's inconsistent. @Brian - True, OP never stated that, but sometimes a little extrapolation is needed when not enough information is given (and OP seems to not be around for comment.)

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` is a very light `forward-only` iterator implementation. If you have a look at [`IEnumerator` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator_members.aspx), there are only three members:

As a solution, you could iterate through the `IEnumerable` manually or use loops.

```
bool MoveNext()
void Reset()
object Current
```

So the only operations are to go forward, reset and to retrieve the current item. There is no built-in ability to *peek* what coming next.

#### IEnumerable version

```
bool someFlag = false;
IEnumerable<object> collection = new object[]{"string", true, 4, DateTime.Now};
using (var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
  while (true ) {
   bool end = enumerator.MoveNext();
   if (!end) {
      if (enumerator.Current.GetType() == typeof(string)) {
        end = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (!end && enumerator.Current.GetType() == typeof(bool))
          someFlag = true;
      }
   } 
   if (end) break;
  }
}
```

#### Loop version

```
bool someFlag = false;
List<object> collection = new object[]{"string", true, 4, DateTime.Now};
int i = 0;
while (true ) {
   bool end = i < collection.Count;
   if (!end) {
      if (collection[i] == typeof(string)) {
        i++;
        end = i < collection.Count;
        if (!end && collection[i] == typeof(bool))
          someFlag = true;
      }
   } 
   if (end) break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If it got so complex already, then you might as well register callback methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Using my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration/3293486#3293486) I came up with this variation as a possible solution. This will work for any type of collection; even those that cannot be indexed.

```
foreach (var item in ForEachHelper.Wrap(collection))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Position=" + item.Index.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Current=" + item.Current.ToString());
    if (item.HasNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next=" + item.Next.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant code.

```
public static class ForEachHelper
{
    public sealed class Item<T>
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public T Current { get; set; }
        public T Next { get; set; }
        public bool HasNext { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Item<T>> Wrap<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            var item = new Item<T>();
            item.Index = 0;
            item.Current = default(T);
            item.Next = default(T);
            item.HasNext = false;
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                item.Current = enumerator.Current;
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    item.Next = enumerator.Current;
                    item.HasNext = true;
                }
                while (item.HasNext)
                {
                    var next = new Item<T>();
                    next.Index = item.Index + 1;
                    next.Current = item.Next;
                    next.Next = default(T);
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        next.Next = enumerator.Current;
                        next.HasNext = true;
                    }
                    var current = item;
                    item = next;
                    yield return current;
                }
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```