# Get index of Enumerator.Current in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(C#) Get index of current foreach iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration)

Good morning,

Is there any way I can get the index of an `Enumerator`'s current element (in the case, a character in a string) without using an ancillary variable? I know this would perhaps be easier if I used a `while` or `for` cicle, but looping through a string using an enumerator is more elegant... The only drawback for the case is that I really need to get each character's current index.

Thank you very much.

Comment: create a wrapper class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, the `IEnumerator` interface does not support such functionality.**

If you require this, you will either have to implement this yourself, or use a different interface like `IList`.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. If you really need the index the most elegant way is to use for a loop. Using the iterator pattern is actually **less** elegant (and slower).

Answer (score 0):

Linq's `Select` has fitting overloads. But you could use something like this:

```
foreach(var x in "ABC".WithIndex())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.Value + " " + x.Index);
}
```

using these helpers:

```
public struct ValueIndexPair<T>
{
    private readonly T mValue;
    private readonly int mIndex;

    public T Value { get { return mValue; } }
    public int Index { get { return mIndex; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + Value + "," + Index + ")";
    }

    public ValueIndexPair(T value, int index)
    {
        mValue = value;
        mIndex = index;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<ValueIndexPair<T>> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T value in sequence)
    {
        yield return new ValueIndexPair<T>(value, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite a lot of noise just to be "more elegant" and to avoid a simple for loop.

Comment: Most of the noise would end up in a library. But I wouldn't use it either. I'd just use Linq or create an additional variable.