# c# how to get last time in foreach statement?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Foreach loop, determine which is the last iteration of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476174/foreach-loop-determine-which-is-the-last-iteration-of-the-loop)

```
foreach (DataRowView row in orderedTable.DefaultView)
{
    if(lasttime) do-something;
}
```

orderedtable is a datatable

does anyone know how to find out whether we are on the last foreach iteration? please keep in mind that i do have duplicates in orderedtable

Comment: What is `lasttime`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: There is a good explanation of why this cannot be done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration

Comment: At first I was like "Jon Skeet doesn't know this"!?  And then I'm like "Oh, it's JOE".

Comment: A pure enumeration (implementing IEnumerator) by definition does not know if the current element is the last. It knows only about the current element, and when the next is required, then it knows if it's the last. You can have a look at the definition of IEnumerator here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.80).aspx. Now, if it's a collection or a List, then you can have the Count.

Comment: Is your name really Joe Skeet? Just wondering ^ ^

Comment: @broke yes we have the same great-grandmother i found out

Comment: @broke he inherited the brains, and i inherited the good looks

Comment: @JOESKEET: I can't tell if you're joking or serious, but either way that was pretty damn funny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `foreach` construct does not know such a thing, since it applies equally to unbounded lists. It just has no way of knowing what is *a last* item.

You can iterate the manual way as  well, though:

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderedTable.DefaultView.Count; i++) {
    DataRowView row = orderedTable.DefaultView[i];
    if (i == orderedTable.DefaulView.Count - 1) {
        // dosomething
    }
}
```

Comment: (Cross your fingers and hope that the `Count` property exists and isn't slow...)

Comment: Well, MSDN lists it. I didn't look for whether it may be optional or not (in fact, the thing with optional methods is something I only know from Java so far).

Answer (score 18):

The **correct** method that works in *all* cases is to use the `IEnumerator<T>` directly:

```
using (var enumerator = orderedTable.DefaultView.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        bool isLast;
        do
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;
            isLast = !enumerator.MoveNext();
            //Do stuff here
        } while (!isLast);
    }
}
```

This method works even if your collection doesn't have a `Count` property, and even if it does, this method will be more efficient if the `Count` property is slow.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach which I don't think anyone posted.  This works well if you don't know the count ahead of time.

```
DataRowView lastRow;
foreach (DataRowView row in orderedTable.DefaultView)
{
    // Do something...

    lastRow = row;
}

if (lastRow != null)
{
  // Do something with last row
}
```

Comment: This method potentially requires code duplication, which we all like to avoid...

Comment: @Lambert: Every row, including the last one, runs the main code block, so no duplication there.  I suppose this way wouldn't work if you *don't* want to `// Do something...` on the last row, since it only lets you run code on the last row *in addition* to what every other row runs.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a regular for loop if you want to have different behavior on the last item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderedTable.DefaultView.Count; i++)
{
    //do stuff
    if (i == orderedTable.DefaultView.Count - 1)
    {
        //do additional special stuff
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that "the other Skeet" has an implementation for a "smart enumerable" which supports a Last property. See the article here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx

With this you could write something like this (I might get the details wrong, haven't tried it out myself):

```
foreach (SmartEnumerable<DataRowView> item in new SmartEnumerable<DataRowView>(orderedTable.DefaultView))
{
    DataRowView row = item.Value;
    if(item.IsLast)
    {
       ///do special stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned in keeping track of your iteration, why not use a `for` instead or a `foreach`?  Then you can simply do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i<orderedTable.DefaultView.Count-1;i++)
{
   if(i==orderedTable.DefaultView.Count-1)
   {
      // Last Row
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foreach get the IEnumerator. If MoveNext returns null the previous was the last one.

for would work too of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like the following:

```
foreach (DataRowView row in orderedTable.DefaultView)
{
    if(row == orderedTable.DefaultView.Last()) do-something;
}
```

But its pretty inefficient.

Comment: Tried this but am getting "DataView does not contain a definition for Last"

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is identical to:

```
if (orderedTable.DefaultView.Rows.Count > 0)
    do-something;
```

If that does not do what you want, you will have to explain what `lastTime` does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, does this help?

```
int lastrow = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
    lastrow++;
    // Do Something
    if (lastrow == (table.Rows.Count - 1))
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: would be better as a for loop, because for already introduces a local variable, but it does work.