# Know when first and last loop in foreach

Tags: c#

Is there way to find out when I'm at the first and last loop on a foreach?

```
foreach(string str in list){
  if(str.isFirst(list) == true){...} 
  if(str.isLast(list) == true){...} 
}
```

^ Something like this?

Comment: i would use an indexed for loop for this.

Comment: A `foreach` knows only the current item. Btw, there are already very similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717120/c-sharp-how-to-get-last-time-in-foreach-statement

Comment: As @TimSchmelter suggested following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717161/477420) shows very good implementation of "is last" for `IEnumerable<T>` which can easily be adapted to "is first". When implementing make sure to define what behavior you want for 0 and 1 cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0) 
    { 
        // is first iteration 
    }
    if (i >= list.Length - 1) 
    { 
        // is last iteration 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh well, guess a for it is

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter

```
int i = 0;
foreach(string str in list)
{
   if(i == 0) { /* first */ }
   if(i == list.Count - 1)  { /* last */ }
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work.  But if you're going to maintain counters, you might as well just use a `for` loop.

Comment: The way the question was worded, this is probably the best solution proposed thus far, although a standard `for` loop does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check whether you are process the first or last item would be the following code :

```
void Process(string[] strings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        var s = strings[i];

        bool isFirst = i == 0;
        bool isLast = i == strings.Length - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way

```
foreach(var kv in list.ToDictionary(k => list.IndexOf(k), v => v))
{
    if (kv.Key == 0) Console.WriteLine("First is {0}", kv.Value);
    if (kv.Key == list.Count - 1) Console.WriteLine("Last is {0}", kv.Value);
}
```

The best option is a for() cycle anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
bool first = true;    
foreach(string str in list)
{
  if(first) 
  {
      //do something
      first = false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: That answers half the question.