# retrieve array index inside Powershell foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I have a loop that uses the foreach keyword:

```
foreach ($ln in Get-Content "c:\ATextFile.txt" )
```

Is it possible to find out the array index referred to by $ln during the iteration?  Or do I need to create and increment a separate counting variable for each loop iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, either use a for loop (something like `(gc c:\ATextFile.txt).count` would be the upper limit ) or an external counter.

Related answer ( for C#, but basically both use the same enumerable concepts): [How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/c-get-index-of-current-foreach-iteration/43029#43029)

Answer (score 4):

Get-Content also add a ReadCount NoteProperty with the current line number.

```
Get-Content foo.txt  | foreach { '{0} {1}' -f $_.ReadCount, $_ }
```