# Iterate through items in arraylist, with an index

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

I want to iterate through items in an arraylist of objects, with an index as well, so that I can transfer a string (part of object/class) into an `ArrayList<String>`

My code:

```
for(PeopleDetails person : people_list; /*not using termination, will terminate at end of people_list */ ;i++){
  /// Code here         
}
```

However I get an error, saying :

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<PeopleDetails> to PeopleDetails`.

What causes this error ?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It's telling you that `people_list` is an `ArrayList` and not `PeopleDetails`.

Comment: How did you declare your `ArrayList`?

Comment: Try posting more relevant code, as in amount wise. Also, why don't you use a normal for loop instead of that _enhanced_ one?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `for-each` statement (I've removed your comment for clarity):-

```
for(PeopleDetails person : people_list;  ;i++)
```

This is:-

```
for(PeopleDetails person : people_list)
```

You're using it like a `for` statement.  If you want to keep an index in a `for-each` you need to do it manually:-

```
 int index = 0;
 for(PeopleDetails person : people_list)
 {
   index++;
 }
```

Further discussion of other ways to iterate over a collection with an index [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop).

Comment: yeah I realized that afterwards. This question is therefore useless... How can I delete it???

Comment: don't need to delete it

Comment: The purpose of this site is that questions are there for other people to search, this may come up again.

Comment: OK, I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

If your `List` `people_list`  is of `String`, Then Try

```
ArrayList<String>people_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(String i :people_list){
    //Code
}
```