# What is Index when inspecting foreach object

Tags: c#, .net

From what I have learned so far, there is no `index` in foreach loops. So, can anyone tell me what is this index field, when inspecing object in visual studio?
[image]

Clearly, it is not index as it would be in for loop, because that number is higher than collection count.

Here is the code, I am inspecing `group` variable.

```
static string LookAndSay (string input) {
            var groups = new Regex("([0-9])\\1*").Matches(input);
            var result = String.Empty;

            foreach (var group in groups)
                result += String.Concat(group.ToString().Length, group.ToString()[0]);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Which object are you inspecting?

Comment: It is `var group in groups` where groups is Regex group collection. I'm inspecting `group`

Comment: It's not visible in the screen shot _which_ object you are inspecting. This `Index` is a property of that object and not related to your `foreach` in any way.

Comment: Is it the `Index` property of the object you are inspecting, e.g. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexCapture.cs,d33b0131e21561d5,references ?

Comment: Really hard to tell from a heavily constrained screenshot. However the inspector gives you *all* information to quickly learn yourself at the first place.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm not using LINQ anywhere.

Comment: @Him: I really hope you didn't downvote on such a false assumption..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're looping on `groups` which consists of [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) than the [Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) property is part of that class.

**Explanation from MSDN**

> The position in the original string where the first character of the
>   captured substring is found.(Inherited from Capture.)

Comment: I think this is it, because in each loop it was incrementing by not consistent value.

Answer (score 0):

It is the current enumerator of class that implements IEnumerable.

See here for more details:

[How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop)

The `foreach` is for iterating over collections that implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It does this by calling [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx) on the collection, which will return an [`Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

This Enumerator has a method and a property:

- MoveNext()
- Current

`Current` returns the object that Enumerator is currently on, `MoveNext` updates `Current` to the next object.

Obviously, the concept of an index is foreign to the concept of enumeration, and cannot be done.

Because of that, most collections are able to be traversed using an indexer and the for loop construct.

I greatly prefer using a for loop in this situation compared to tracking the index with a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

So, `Index` is a property of whatever object you are inspecting. This may or may not have anything to do with `foreach`--we can't tell. But for what it's worth: `foreach` operates by calling an inherited `GetEnumerator` method in whatever the collection is you are looping through. The `GetEnumerator` method tells it what object to get next (internally, it might use that Index value), returns the Current object, and specifies what type the current object is. More on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(v=vs.71).aspx