# get item index in Foreach

Tags: macros, kentico

I have MyCustomMacro that returns me list of strings.
I need to show this list with custom separator beetwen list elements.

```
{% 
foreach (ev in MyCustomMacro("events") )
{ 
  ev + " | "; 
};
#%}
```

but this code also addes " | " after last element.

How can i check that element is last in the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use join method of string class:

{% string.join("|", MyCustomMacro("events")) %}

Comment: This code works only in Kentico CMS, it's a K# macro expression. In C# you need to use only  `string.join("|", new string[]{})`

Answer (score 3):

if you can get the values in a string array, you can do:

```
string.Join("|", events[])
```

[Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)

Answer (score 2):

I think a much efficient way is to use string StringBuilder class.

Something on these lines.

```
{%
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (ev in MyCustomMacro("events") )
  { 
    builder.append(ev + " | "); 
  };
  result = String.Join("|", builder.Split('|'));
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easly by this:

```
{% result="";
   foreach (ev in MyCustomMacro("events") )
    { 
     result+= ev + " | "; 
    };
   result.TrimEnd(" | ")
%}
```

Comment: This works but somewhat of a hack.  Use a method which is already created for this like `string.Join()`