# How to compare sequential elements in a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

In a foreach loop I want to compare an element with the previous element that was read. How can I do that? What is the syntax for addressing a previous element in a foreach loop?

Comment: Why not change it to a `for(int i =0; i < listSize; i++)` so you can access the element before?

Comment: You could simply do it by using `temp variable`.

Comment: What is the "previous" element when you're at the start of the loop? (null, or perhaps you actually want to start looping from the second item)

Comment: `For loop` sometime has worse peformance than a `foreach loop` because you must go find the element `i` in a long `Collection`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Who cares? Performance is not an argument. (In)ability to directly index items would be.

Comment: Foreach is suppose to encapsulate the way you iterate over a collection, Therefore, if you want to compare elements in a specific order, you should iterate the collection differently and use indexes for doing that.

Comment: [This answer has some nice information about how the `foreach` loop works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43029/833070)

Comment: @PhamX.Bach and somtimes `foreach loop` has worse performance than `for loop`, it depends on what is being done and the collection you are working with.

Comment: Setting a variable outside the loop that holds the previous item could be a solution. Also what @Draken suggests is good

Answer (score 8):

You don't have that option built in with a `foreach` loop.
You can either switch to a `for` loop or use a variable.

Suppose you iterate through a list of objects, these are your options:

```
object prev = null;
foreach(var current in myListOfObjects)
{
    if(current == prev)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    // don't forget the next row!
    prev = current;
}
```

or

```
for(var i = 1; i < myListOfObjects.count, i++) // Note: starting from 1 to avoid another condition inside the loop.
{
    if(myListOfObjects[i] == myListOfObjects[i-1])
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything is better with <strike>Bluetooth</strike> extension methods:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public struct CurrentAndPrevious<T>
    {
        public T Current { get; private set; }
        public T Previous { get; private set; }

        public CurrentAndPrevious(T current, T previous) : this()
        {
            Previous = previous;
            Current = current;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<CurrentAndPrevious<T>> WithPrevious<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var previous = default(T);

        using(var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return new CurrentAndPrevious<T>(enumerator.Current, previous);
                previous = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}

var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
foreach(var item in items.WithPrevious())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Previous + " " + item.Current);
}
```

You might need to tweak this depending on how you want first and last elements handled.

Comment: Your foreach example might be a little confusing for someone new to C#, it might be better to split array initization and the use of .WithPrevious().

Comment: While I love this solution, I hate the use of `Tuple` here. Its so unintuative what `Item1` and `Item2` are. For the sake of declaring a struct with properties `Current` and `Previous` ... I'd personally do that.

Comment: @Jamiec My thoughts exactly, but I could not come up with a good name for this "value with previous value" type thing.

Comment: `EnumerableElementWithPrevious<T>` - although thats quite verbose. And now im wondering if a struct can be generic... might need to be a class.

Comment: @Jamiec Updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over a bit modified `source` instead of initial, say `ListOfMyObjects`:

```
MyObject prior = default(MyObject);

var source = ListOfMyObjects
  .Select(item => {
     var result = new {
       Current = item,
       Prior = prior, 
     };

     prior = item; // side effect, not a good practice

     return result;  
  });
```

So you can loop

```
foreach(var item in source) {
  if (item.Prior == item.Current) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` itself has *no* syntax 'for addressing a previous element'. There are two options, depending on the characteristics of the collection and also the notion of a 'previous' element in respect of the first one. The following the examples are a little bit simplistic, but you should be able to choose the right path and fine-tune the details.

#### Option 1: Use a temporary variable

Works well if there's no cheap (performance-wise) way to index elements in the sequence, and you are OK with 'pretending' there's an empty (`null`, or `default(T)`) item before the very first item.

```
T previous = default(T);  // corresponds to null for reference types
foreach (T item in sequence)
{
     … work with previous and item here…

     // the current 'item' is the new 'previous' for the next iteration
     previous = item;
}
```

Note that if T is a value type, your would be actually copying the values themselves.

#### Option 2: Use a `for` loop and indexing

Works well if there *is* a cheap (performance-wise) way to index individual elements directly. `List<T>` and arrays are good examples here.

```
// indexing from 1, i.e. from the second item in the sequence
for (int i = 1; i < sequence.Count; i++)
{
    var previous = sequence[i-1]; // this is obviously the previous item
    var current = sequence[i];    // this is obviously the current item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to using a temp variable, however this solution moves the scope of the temp variable inside the loop

```
var collection = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var currentIndex = collection.IndexOf(item);
    if (currentIndex > 0 && currentIndex < collection.Count)
    {
        var previousItem = collection[currentIndex - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by Pham X, one easy way to do this would be a temp variable.

```
ObjectType temp_object = null;
foreach(var entry in ListOfObjects)
{
    if(temp_object==null)
    {
        //this is the first time through...
        temp_object=entry;
    }
    else
    {
        //it's anything after the first loop
        if(entry==temp_object) Console.WriteLine("There is a match between two entries.");
        else temp_object=entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: you will only ever set `temp_object` once.