# How to iterate a `foreach loop` between index 40-60?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have a simple question that I can't find a clean answer to when I google.

How do I iterate a `foreach loop` between index 40-60 and get the values for the indexes?

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list1.Add(i);
}
foreach (var i in list1) 
{
    //How to iterate between index: 40 to 60 ?
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `foreach`? You should just use a regular `for` there and specify 40 and 60 as the start and end indices.

Comment: @Herohtar, I like to test if foreach is faster then the for loop as I am micro-optimizing some loops. The foreach loop is faster when iterating all elements and I like to try to put a start and end index as well.

Comment: This might help with your optimization question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach (Hint: `for` is faster)

Comment: @Andreas `foreach` would never be faster than `for` when dealing with a collection that is indexed.  It is if say you used `ElementAt` on something that had to iterated the collection to get to the position.

Comment: @juharr, yes you are right. It seems that the for loop is the one to choose if needing to iterate between 2 indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a regular `for` loop:

```cs
for (int i = 40; i < 60; ++i)
{
    int value = list1[i];
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Note - if you want to get the value for index 60 too (i.e., the range is inclusive), you should use the `<=` operator instead of `<`.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the best approach after all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Foreach loop doesn't use an index for traversing an array or collection. They take advantage of the enumerator in an IEnumerable. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop) has a great explanation of that.

If you want you can add an int before the foreach loop and increment within the loop, but that's all you can do. I would advise that you filter your list1 beforehand and then use it in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a foreach then you need to write this

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(40, 20))
{
    list1.Add(i);
}
```

But, lacking better info on your request to use foreach, then I agree to use a standard for-loop

Comment: That Enumerable.Range was actually almost 3 times slower than the `for-loop` So perheps the for loop is the one to choose after all if one needs to iterate between 2 indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other more appropriate answers (e.g. just use a `for` loop), here's a solution that uses the [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) overload that provides the index of the element as a parameter to the predicate:

```
foreach (var i in list1.Where((x, index) => index >= 40 && index <= 60))
{
    //How to iterate between index: 40 to 60 ?
}
```

Comment: This definitely will be much slower than a `for` loop, which is what the OP is actually after based on his comments.

Comment: According to the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e2d8014ab698cbfc,references), this will enumerate all content of the list. Definitely far slower than even a naive .Skip(40).Take(20)

Comment: Yes you are right. I noticed almost 10 times slower with this approach actually.