# How to get index in C# foreach

Tags: c#, excel

I am looping my table data and trying to place table rows in excel file but I need to get index of each row in order to make rows in my excel file.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = row["Id"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = row["ProductId"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = row["OrderQuantity"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = row["CustomerID"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = row["OrderDate"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = row["Tax"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 7] = row["Total"].ToString();
  xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 8] = row["Net"].ToString();
}
```

All I need is the way to replace `2` (excel row number) in `xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 8]` with foreach `index` number so instead of static `row 2` it will be `row 3, 4,5,6,...` based on how many rows I have in database.

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: use a local variable declared outside the loop and incremented inside it or switch to a for loop for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++){}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @T.Schwarz sorry I didn't understand! then how do I get my `row["Id"]`?

Comment: You might use LINQ: `foreach(var (row,index) in dt.Rows.Select((v,i) => (v,i)))`

Comment: int rowcount = 0; foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){  xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowcount, 1] = row["Id"].ToString(); ....... rowcount++;}

Comment: @SomeBody It return error `CS8130`

Comment: @T.Schwarz Thank you, now in console it says `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: @mjwills `cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a local variable outside a foreach loop and increment it until last row. This will hold current row. e.g

```
int i=0; 
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{

xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = row["Id"].ToString(); 
i++; 
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an int an increment that with every iteration.
For example (dummy code):

```
    int count = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[count, 1] = row["Id"].ToString();
      ...
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[count, 8] = row["Net"].ToString();
      count ++;
    }
```

You can of course initialize the value of count from 2 if that suits your needs. It will just increment it.