# is this possible to get index of foreach loop in c#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i want to update my db table with foreach loop and what i need is to get index of foreach loop to get right index of declared array to sum with count of my db.

```
byte[] OldSelectedProductsCount = ThisFactor.BuffetServices.Where(q => q.FactorID == ThisFactor.FactorID).Select(q => q.Count).ToArray();

giveBackBuffets.ForEach(t => _Buffet.Update(new BuffetViewModel()
{
    BuffetID = t.BuffetID,
    Name = t.Name,
    Price = t.Price,
    Count = t.Count + OldSelectedProductsCount[idexofforeachloop],
 }));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the index of the current iteration of a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021/how-do-you-get-the-index-of-the-current-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Or you can use a 'for' loop instead..

Comment: @DarkBee no it doesnt work for me

Comment: "*it doesnt work for me*" - That question has 2 pages full of answers... Just saying doesn't work won't cut it. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]

Comment: Hopefully this is just a hobby project. Otherwise, you should know that updating a database table by reading all of the rows, then performing some computation outside of the database and then writing changes back to the database (ignoring the possibility of any concurrent updates) is about the worst way of doing things.

Comment: @DarkBee main problem is i want to update my db with parameters and i want to foreach through my viewmodel

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever any suggestion or article ?what is the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead of the foreach loop

```
    byte[] oldSelectedProductsCount = ThisFactor.BuffetServices.Where(q => q.FactorID == ThisFactor.FactorID).Select(q => q.Count).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < giveBackBuffets.Count; i++)
    {

        _Buffet.Update(new BuffetViewModel()
        {
            BuffetID = giveBackBuffets[i].BuffetID,
            Name = giveBackBuffets[i].Name,
            Price = giveBackBuffets[i].Price,
            Count = giveBackBuffets[i].Count + oldSelectedProductsCount[i],
        });
    }
```

Comment: it works pretty good Maybe the problem was that I was wrongly insisting on this issue to  use foreach...anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"foreach loop" typically refers to

```
foreach(var item in myCollection){...}
```

The `.ForEach(...)` is a common LINQ-style extension method, but crucially not part of the framework itself. To get the index in this you can combine it with a select to return a pair of item and index:

```
myCollection
  .Select((item, index) => ( item, index ))
  .ForEach(p => {
     var item = p.item;
     var index = p.index;
     ...
});
```

In the same way the [top answer in the almost identical question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11437562/12342238). I would however consider just making a regular foreach loop instead. The extension method variant seem less readable to me in this case.

Comment: *"LINQ-style extension method"* - More often, it's a method implemented by `List<T>`. People do implement their own extension method, but too often we see excessive `ToList` calls just to get access to that implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `indexOfForeachLoop` variable at the beginning:

```
byte[] OldSelectedProductsCount = ThisFactor.BuffetServices.Where(q => q.FactorID == ThisFactor.FactorID).Select(q => q.Count).ToArray();

int indexOfForeachLoop = 0;
giveBackBuffets.ForEach(t => 
{
    _Buffet.Update(new BuffetViewModel()
    {
        BuffetID = t.BuffetID,
        Name = t.Name,
        Price = t.Price,
        Count = t.Count + OldSelectedProductsCount[indexOfForeachLoop],
    })
    indexOfForeachLoop++;
});
```

or more sexy/reusable way would be to crate Extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Extension method for IList<T> to take advantage of indexing
    public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        // Check for null to avoid NullReferenceException
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        // Use a for loop to iterate over the list
        for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        {
            action(list[index], index); // Execute the action, passing the item and its index
        }
    }
}
```

and then you would use it like:

```
giveBackBuffets.ForEachWithIndex((t, index) => _Buffet.Update(new BuffetViewModel
    {
        BuffetID = t.BuffetID,
        Name = t.Name,
        Price = t.Price,
        // Use the index to access the corresponding element in OldSelectedProductsCount
        Count = t.Count + OldSelectedProductsCount[index], 
    });
);
```